# select random id from set of elements with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a set of elements on a page all with the same class but all have a different id. I am looking to select a random element and obtain its id so it can then be used in another function.

```
<div id="7469" class="element"> ... </div>
<div id="0184" class="element"> ... </div>
<div id="3986" class="element"> ... </div>
<div id="1295" class="element"> ... </div>
<div id="5704" class="element"> ... </div>
and so on...
```

Comment: If you select using `$('.element')` you can then pick a random number from 0 to the `length` of the resulting object and select one specific element by index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate index randomly and get element based on the index. Use [`Math.random`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) and jQuery [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq) methods for that.

```js
var $ele = $('.element');

console.log($ele.eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*($ele.length - 1))).attr('id'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="7469" class="element">...</div>
<div id="0184" class="element">...</div>
<div id="3986" class="element">...</div>
<div id="1295" class="element">...</div>
<div id="5704" class="element">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First gather all divs with `element` class.

```
var elements = $(".element");
```

And then

```
var randomelement = elements[Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length)];
var randomid = $(elements[randomelement].attr("id"))
console.log(randomid)
```

See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915096/get-random-item-from-javascript-array)