# Javascript: generating random image upon clicking on link

Tags: javascript

I am trying to generate random images by clicking on hyperlink. For that I have used random function to generate random image. but it's not working. Can anyone correct me ?

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="aclick"><p style="text-align: center;"> Catalogue </p> </a>


    <script language="JavaScript">
// set image list
var images = new Array();
images[0] = "final_images/book.jpg";
images[1] = "final_images/neck.jpeg";
images[2] = "final_images/shoes.jpg";
images[3] = "final_images/mixture.jpeg";
images[4] = "final_images/earing.jpg";

var link = document.getElementById('aclick');
link.addEventListener("click",function() {
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
});

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get random item from JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915096/get-random-item-from-javascript-array)

Comment: But you dont have any `<img>` element, you need this element and set the `src` with the some value of array `images`

Comment: @kip yaa got it......

Answer (score 0):

```js
link.addEventListener("click",function() {
    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
    console.log('link : ',images[randomNum]);
});
```