# populate array with 4 random different non-repeating objects with some filters ES6+

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I need a little help to improve a function where I'm populating an array with 4 random different non-repeating recipes objects using the id of the recipes, but I need to add an additional condition where the recipes should be 1 breakfast, 1 lunch, 1 snack and 1 dinner, for example:

example of JSON with recipes

```js
[
  {
    recipeId: 1,
    recipeTypeId: 1, // breakFast
    "description": "someRecipe",
    "img": "someImgBase64",
  },
  {
    recipeId: 2,
    recipeTypeId: 2, // lunch
    "description": "someRecipe",
    "img": "someImgBase64",
  },
  {
    recipeId: 3,
    recipeTypeId: 3, // snack
    "description": "someRecipe",
    "img": "someImgBase64",
  },
  {
    recipeId: 4,
    recipeTypeId: 4, // dinner
    "description": "someRecipe",
    "img": "someImgBase64",
  },
  {
    recipeId: 5,
    recipeTypeId: 1, // breakfast
    "description": "someRecipe",
    "img": "someImgBase64",
  }
]
```

this is my function:

```js
randomRecipes() {
  // previously saved recipes from api
  localStorage.getItem('recipesList');
  // random generator
  const randomIndex = new Set();
  const recommendedRandomRecipes: [] = [];
  while (randomIndex.size < 4) {
    randomIndex.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * recipes.length));
  }
  randomIndex.forEach(i => recommendedRandomRecipes.push(recipes[Number(i)]));
  localStorage.addItem('recommendedRecipes', recommendedRandomRecipes);
  this.recipes = recommendedRandomRecipes;
}
```

the result I want:

```
recommendedRandomRecipes [1,2,3,4] or [2,3,4,5]
```

what I don't want

```
recommendedRandomRecipes [1,2,3,5] // 2 breakfast in the array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably many different ways to do this, but here's the strategy I can think of. Basically, you want to generate a list of recipes that contain **only one randomly chosen reipce per `recipeTypeId`**. Here are some steps that we can go through:

1. To accommodate arbitrary number of `recipeTypeId`, we first iterate through the array and collect all unique values. This can be done by using [`new Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and adding them to it
2. Then, we iterate through this unique set of recipe types. For each set, we generate a filtered array (from the original recipes list), which contains all recipes for a given recipe type. We then [pick a random item from there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915096/get-random-item-from-javascript-array).
3. Collect all these items and only return their `recipeId`
4. Optionally, sort them in increasing order (as your desired output suggests).

See proof-of-concept:

```js
const recipesList = [
  {
    recipeId: 1,
    recipeTypeId: 1, // breakFast
    "description": "someRecipe",
    "img": "someImgBase64",
  },
  {
    recipeId: 2,
    recipeTypeId: 2, // lunch
    "description": "someRecipe",
    "img": "someImgBase64",
  },
  {
    recipeId: 3,
    recipeTypeId: 3, // snack
    "description": "someRecipe",
    "img": "someImgBase64",
  },
  {
    recipeId: 4,
    recipeTypeId: 4, // dinner
    "description": "someRecipe",
    "img": "someImgBase64",
  },
  {
    recipeId: 5,
    recipeTypeId: 1, // breakfast
    "description": "someRecipe",
    "img": "someImgBase64",
  }
];

// Collect unique recipeTypeId
const recipeTypes = new Set();
recipesList.forEach((recipe) => recipeTypes.add(recipe.recipeTypeId));

// Go through unique recipe types and return a randomly chosen recipe
const recipeCombos = Array.from(recipeTypes).map((type) => {
  const filteredRecipesByType = recipesList.filter((recipe) => {
    return recipe.recipeTypeId === type;
  });
  
  // Retrieve random recipe in this filtered collection
  const randomRecipeByType = filteredRecipesByType[Math.floor(Math.random() * filteredRecipesByType.length)];
  
  // Since you only want the recipeId, we return that property only
  return randomRecipeByType.recipeId;
});

// For your given data, the only possible combinations are:
// [1,2,3,4]
// [2,3,4,5]
console.log(recipeCombos.sort());
```

Comment: @JordanBlakeTold No problem, glad to be able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Explanations in a code snippet, please take a look

```js
var recipes = [
  {
    recipeId: 1,
    recipeTypeId: 1, // breakFast
    "description": "someRecipe",
    "img": "someImgBase64",
  },
  {
    recipeId: 2,
    recipeTypeId: 2, // lunch
    "description": "someRecipe",
    "img": "someImgBase64",
  },
  {
    recipeId: 3,
    recipeTypeId: 3, // snack
    "description": "someRecipe",
    "img": "someImgBase64",
  },
  {
    recipeId: 4,
    recipeTypeId: 4, // dinner
    "description": "someRecipe",
    "img": "someImgBase64",
  },
  {
    recipeId: 5,
    recipeTypeId: 1, // breakfast
    "description": "someRecipe",
    "img": "someImgBase64",
  }
]

function randomRecipes(recipes) {
  // 1. taking a count of all the  different recipeTypeIds, it could be not always 4. could be 3, could be 5, so
  var recipeTypeIdsLegth = recipes.reduce((acc, item) => acc.indexOf(item.recipeTypeId) == -1 ? [...acc, item.recipeTypeId] : acc, []).length;
  console.log(recipeTypeIdsLegth) // 4

  // 2. clone original array, because we will play and modify it
  let clonedRecipes = [...recipes]

  // 3 declaring a result arrray
  var recommendedRandomRecipes = []

  // 4. create a loop
  for (i = 0; i < recipeTypeIdsLegth; i++) {
    
    // 5. randomindex
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * clonedRecipes.length);

    // 6. push recipe to result array
    recommendedRandomRecipes.push(clonedRecipes[randomIndex]);

    // 7. main magic. remove all the recipies with the same clonedRecipes[randomIndex].recipeTypeId from clonedRecipes
    clonedRecipes = clonedRecipes.filter(item => item.recipeTypeId !== clonedRecipes[randomIndex].recipeTypeId)
  }

  // 8. returning
  return recommendedRandomRecipes;
}

var recommendedRandomRecipes = randomRecipes(recipes);

console.log(recommendedRandomRecipes);
```