# turning a string to and array then passing to another function by chance javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

i made a fetch request (i turned a text into array)and i want them to pass each array element by accident in another function.

```
function randomSingleWord() {
    fetch('http://www.randomtext.me/api/').then(res => res.json() )
    .then(data => data.text_out.split(' ');
    return data //random or by order single word
}
```

Comment: It's 2020, we have `await` now. That would help trim down how much code you have to write.

Comment: Is this asking "How do I shuffle an array in JavaScript?" or "How do I pick a random element from a JavaScript array?"

Comment: yes i am asking this questions."How do I shuffle an array in JavaScript?" or "How do I pick a random element from a JavaScript array?"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a random item from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915096/get-a-random-item-from-a-javascript-array)

Comment: Because `fetch` is asynchronous, this `return data` is meaningless.  That is, this random word function will always return undefined.  I think first you need to return the result of `fetch` (on the first line ```return fetch(...```.  The caller will then have a promise which it can use like ```randomSingleWord.then((arrayOfWords) => { })``` and that function can do whatever it wants with the `arrayOfWords`.

Answer (score 1):

This has some asynchronous problems that `await` can fix:

```
async function randomSingleWord() {
  let data = await fetch('http://www.randomtext.me/api/');

  let words = data.text_out.split(' ');

  return words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
}
```

Where this is now a Promise, so `then` or `await` applies.

Comment: what about adding .json?

Comment: Is this data JSON or not? If it is, `JSON.parse` can tackle it.