# How do I randomize the outcome of an array, then link it to a conditional

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I want to randomize the results from the `person` array. How do I connect it to the `if` statement so it randomizes the person each time, and if I load it it gives me a different sentence each time.

```
let placea = 'Shopping Mall'
let placeb = 'Library'

let person = ['John', 'Sam', 'Ryan', 'Liam', 'David']

if (person === 'John' || person === 'Liam' || person === 'Sam') {
  console.log(`Lets go to the ${placea}`)
} else {
  console.log(`I love quiet places, lets go to the ${placeb}`)
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Get a random item from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915096/get-a-random-item-from-a-javascript-array)

Comment: "so it randomizes the person each time" <= "each time" implies repetition of some sort.  It is unclear in your question where that repetition is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want "person" to refer to a random person from your array and not the array itself.

A good trick to remember is how to get a random element from an array `a` (works with any array that isn't empty):

```
const a = [1, 2, 3];
const randomElement = a[Math.floor(Math.random() * a.length)];
```

Math.random gives a random float from 0 to almost 1

multiply it by the array length to get a random float from 0 to almost array length

Math.floor chops the decimal off to get a random int from 0 to array length - 1

```js
let placea = 'Shopping Mall'
let placeb = 'Library'

let people = ['John', 'Sam', 'Ryan', 'Liam', 'David'];
let person = people[Math.floor(Math.random() * people.length)];

if (person === 'John' || person === 'Liam' || person === 'Sam') {
  console.log(`Lets go to the ${placea}`)
} else {
  console.log(`I love quiet places, lets go to the ${placeb}`)
}
```