# Is there a random function in javascript that doesn't take the range of two numbers?

Tags: javascript, random

I want the computer to randomly choose either 8 or 2.
I tried doing (Math.random()*8)+2, it chooses a random number BETWEEN 8 and 2 but I want the computer to randomly choose 8 or 2.

So I tried a different way, and I did this:

```
if(b==0){
var a = 2;
}
else{
var a = 8;
}
```

However, it is not working. Is there a more efficient and better way?

Thank you,
Paul

Comment: Choose a random number of either 0 or 1. 0 maps to 8 and 1 maps to 2. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915096/get-a-random-item-from-a-javascript-array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do.

```
function randomSelection(values) {
  return values[Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length)];
}

numbers = [2,8];
randomSelection(numbers);
```