# How to randomize array

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I am trying to randomize the values in an array.

Is it acceptable to type out my code like this:

```
var buttonColours = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
var randomChosenColour = Math.random(buttonColours.length);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a random item from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915096/get-a-random-item-from-a-javascript-array)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to randomize (shuffle) a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.
`random()` return number between `0-1.`
use `Math.floor(Math.random() * buttonColours.length)`

Comment: oh, yea...done! many thanks again.