# random images change with every refresh made

Tags: javascript, html

so I have linked two images in HTML from the folder: images/ however in javascript I'm trying to make these images for the dice to randomly change after every time refreshes.
I'm not sure why isn't working

here is the HTML code

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Refresh Me</h1>

  <div class="dice">
    <p>Player 1</p>
    <img class="img1" src="images/dice6.png">
  </div>

  <div class="dice">
    <p>Player 2</p>
    <img class="img2" src="images/dice6.png">
  </div>

    </div>
```

and here is the js code

```
imgArray = [
"dice1.png",
"dice2.png",
"dice3.png",
"dice4.png",
"dice5.png",
"dice6.png"
]


function images(){
  // the random images
  var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArray.length);
  // get images at randomNumber1
  selectedImages = imgArray[randomNumber1]
  // display the images()
  document.getElementByClassName("img1").src = "./images/${selectedImages}"

}
```

Note: I'm a new learner still trying to understand javascript. thank you for your humble reply and help. and if isn't too much to make the explanation simple so I could follow.

after fixing the code above

```
function images(){
  // the random images
  var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArray.length);
  // get images at randomNumber1
  selectedImages = imgArray[randomNumber1]
  // display the images()
  document.getElementsByClassName("img1")[0].src = './images/${selectedImages}'
}

window.onload = images;
```

I have problem when I refresh the page this is what it does show

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LIqH.jpg)

again thank you for your help.

[here what it show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTJY7.jpg)

okay fixed, here I did change it with

```
function images(){
  // the random images
  var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArray.length);
  // get images at randomNumber1
  selectedImages = imgArray[randomNumber1]
  // display the images()
  document.getElementsByClassName("img1")[0].src = 'images/' + selectedImages;
  document.getElementsByClassName("img2")[0].src = 'images/' + selectedImages;
}

window.onload = images;
```

Comment: this syntax ${selectedImages} (template literals) needs `` . It should be \`/images/${selectedImages}\`

Comment: replace `"` with `\`` in `.src = ""`

Comment: It is `getElementsByClassName` not `getElementByClassName`. It also returns a collection instead of a single element so you need to access them by index e.g. `getElementsByClassName('img1')[0].src = ...`

Comment: Very helpful SO post for finding random item in array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915096/get-a-random-item-from-a-javascript-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues here:

1. `getElementbyClassName` is not a valid function. It should be `getElementsByClassName` which returns an array-like collection of elements having that class name. So select the first value by writing `getElementsByClassName[0]`.
2. Replace double quotes by single quotes here: `'images/' + selectedImages`
3. Don't forget to call the function when the windows is loaded.

Final Code:

```
function images(){
  // the random images
  var randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * imgArray.length);
  // get images at randomNumber1
  selectedImages = imgArray[randomNumber1]
  // display the images()
  document.getElementsByClassName("img1")[0].src = 'images/' + selectedImages;
}

window.onload = images;
```

Comment: FYI: [getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a (live) [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) not an array. Though the structure is similar don't expect to be able to use methods like forEach or map.

Comment: thank you all for the help. i have changed the one I have mistaken with, however, when I refresh the page doesn't change anything, the dice do not change. please advice

Comment: @Reyno oh what is the correct way for the getElementsByClassName instead?

Comment: @SamiKaddoura  check the updated answer

Comment: @Reyno added that clarification. thank you.

Comment: thank you @muhammed Jaseem for the explanation however the IMG after refreshing not change. is there something wrong I have done?

Comment: Try the updated one again?

Comment: yes i have and now when i refresh the page doesn't show, when I refresh the page it shows there is no img

Comment: @SamiKaddoura hover on the image icon and check if it is showing the correct URL or if something is wrong with the path.

Comment: @Muhammed Jaseem, kindly look above i linked a screen shot for what it does show in the src and advice. thanks

Comment: You are still using the old code : )

Comment: worked, .. @Muhammed Jaseem, yes sorry didn't notice you have updated till now, I change it and now work like a charm, thank you so much..and thank you all

Comment: Sett. Please accept the answer xD

Comment: @muhammed Jaseem, done :D . thanks bro,