# How to give random unique role to all of my users in js?

Tags: javascript

```js
const role = [
{
 name: 'Hitman'
},
{
 name: 'Doctor'
},
{
 name: 'Nurse'
}
]
```

This is my array of objects now this is my users

```js
const user = ['James', 'Harden']
```

notice there are only two, so only two random roles will used from my array of objects now the result i want is

```js
 [
{
 name: 'Hitman'
 User: 'Harden'
},
{
 name: 'Nurse'
 User: 'James'
}
]
```

See, random user for a random role how can i do that?

Comment: You want the role to be unique? So there can't be e.g. 2 Hitmans or 2 Nurses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution:

Since you want to prevent duplicate item from array, the best way is to copy the array and remove the specific item every time from the created array. This could keep the orignial data.

```js
const role = [{ name: 'Hitman', img: 'hitman.png'},{ name: 'Doctor', img: 'doc.png'},{ name: 'Nurse', img: 'nurse.png'}]

const user = ['James', 'Harden', "Jason", "Iris"]
let test = []
let left = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(role))
for (let i of user) {
  if (left.length > 0) {
    let ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * left.length)
    test.push({ user: i,name: left[ran].name,img: left[ran].img})
    left.splice(ran, 1)
  } else {
 test.push({user: i,name: "Hitman",img:'hitman.png'})
  }
}
console.log(test)
```

Comment: Thankyou but when the array is like this..

const user = ['James', 'Harden', 'Stephen', 'Curry']

notice there are only 3 roles which is Doctor Hitman and Nurse, now i want them to give all unique role, but! if all roles are taken i want the people who dont have unique role be a Hitman

Comment: @VcutDev, just updated the code. Check if it works now and tell me：）

Answer (score 0):

Use this answer to
[Get a random item from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915096/get-a-random-item-from-a-javascript-array)

Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to loop through your users and choose a random role for each.

```js
const role = [{
    name: 'Hitman'
  },
  {
    name: 'Doctor'
  },
  {
    name: 'Nurse'
  }
];

const user = ['James', 'Harden'];

const users = user.map(name => ({
  name: role[Math.floor(Math.random() * role.length)].name,
  User: name
}));

console.log(users);
```

Comment: In order the values to be unique, you need the name in the result to be this: `name: role.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * role.length), 1)[0].name`

Answer (score 0):

In order to do it uniquely, perform a random shuffle on the array, then assign the values sequentially...

```js
// this thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976/294949
function shuffle(array) {
  let currentIndex = array.length, randomIndex;
  while (currentIndex != 0) {
    // Pick a remaining element...
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex--;
    // And swap it with the current element.
    [array[currentIndex], array[randomIndex]] = [
      array[randomIndex], array[currentIndex]
    ];
  }
  return array;
}

let role = [{
    name: 'Hitman'
  },
  {
    name: 'Doctor'
  },
  {
    name: 'Nurse'
  }
];

shuffle(role);  // when this is run, the role array is randomly reordered

const user = ['James', 'Harden', 'Curry', 'Thompson', 'Green'];
// assign roles sequentially, like dealing cards from the top of a shuffled deck
const usersWithRoles = user.map((user, index) => {
  let roleName = index < role.length ? role[index].name : 'Hitman'
  return { name: user, roleName  };
});
console.log(usersWithRoles);
```

Comment: Thankyou but when the array is like this..

const user = ['James', 'Harden', 'Stephen', 'Curry']

notice there are only 3 roles which is Doctor Hitman and Nurse, now i want them to give all unique role, but! if all roles are taken i want the people who dont have unique role be a Hitman

Comment: Edited to provide a default value when the names exceed the roles. (And added more GS Warriors names :-)