# What constitutes "one action" in "one line - one action"?

Tags: readability, code-readability

I was going through [this Javascript tutorial](https://javascript.info/operators) when I came across a call for “one line – one action”.

> ```
> alert( 2 * counter++ );
> ```
>
> Though technically okay, such notation usually makes code less readable. One line does multiple things – not good.
>
> While reading code, a fast “vertical” eye-scan can easily miss something like counter++ and it won’t be obvious that the variable increased.
>
> We advise a style of “one line – one action”:
>
> ```
> alert( 2 * counter );
> counter++;
> ```

Later, I came across [a very highly upvoted answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915096/get-a-random-item-from-a-javascript-array):

> ```
> const randomElement = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
> ```

Which looks like a lot of actions to me.

I understand style is a matter of personal preference, but I wonder if more experienced programmers might see the above as constituting one larger action (and so still one line - one action).

I searched through the internet but could not find an authoritative source in describing what I was looking for regarding "one line - one action".

Answer (score 1):

*If you are unsure, add another variable.*

As you correctly said, there are a lot of operations in this line:

```
const randomElement = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
```

If you want to make your code more readable, I would write something like this:

```
const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);
const randomElement = array[index];
```

In addition, if you get an exception / error on these lines, you can differentiate if the index calculation or something with the array is wrong.