# How to randomly select objects from an array without repeatation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need it to
make a quiz project.. I want random selection of questions from like 30 blocks of objects in an array....

Tried a lot but couldnt find a way to randomly select it... I tried many ways yt tutorials... But there are none meeting my requirements

Comment: Randomly sort ([shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)) the array and take the first x objects. Simple and avoids duplicates.

Comment: Can you post what you've tried already and we can have a look.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#getting_a_random_number_between_two_values where min is 0 and max is length of array minus 1

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add some code, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Provide sample array data, btw you are probably asking for shuffling an array

Comment: Perhaps have a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get a random item from a JavaScript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5915096/get-a-random-item-from-a-javascript-array)

Answer (score 1):

You can get a random index using

`let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)`,

then you should remove the elment from the array maybe using
`arr.splice(i ,1)`.

This could be a sample:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5];


for(let n in arr)
  removeRandom(arr);


function removeRandom(arr){

  let i = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);

  let str= "pre "

  for(let n in arr)
   str += arr[n] ;
  
  console.log("str "+str)
  console.log("arr[i] " + arr[i]);

  arr.splice(i ,1);
 
  str= "post "

  for(let n in arr)
   str += arr[n] ;
  
  console.log("str "+str)
}
```