# What is the "double tilde" (~~) operator in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm seeing this in some code, and I have no idea what it does:

```
var jdn = function(y, m, d) {
  var tmp = (m <= 2 ? -1 : 0);
  return ~~((1461 * (y + 4800 + tmp)) / 4) + 
         ~~((367 * (m - 2 - 12 * tmp)) / 12) - 
         ~~((3 * ((y + 4900 + tmp) / 100)) / 4) + 
         d - 2483620;
};
```

What's the `~~` operator do?

Comment: You've probably figured it out by now but it returns the number of days between the millennium and a given date

Comment: in simple words, it converts '9' into a number 9. And its must faster than Math.floor() even with IE8
if you do the following in console:
typeof ~~'9'//number

Comment: Math.trunc(), not Math.floor()

Answer (score 912, accepted):

That `~~` is a double [Bitwise NOT operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT).

It is used as a [faster substitute for `Math.floor()`](http://rocha.la/JavaScript-bitwise-operators-in-practice) for *positive* numbers. It does not return the same result as `Math.floor()` for negative numbers, as it just chops off the part after the decimal (see other answers for examples of this).

Comment: +1 Was not aware that it floored the value, but I guess it makes sense. (However aren't bitwise operators slower in JavaScript than arithmetic operators making this a slower method?)

Comment: @ghoppe: Worth noting that it differs from `.floor()` in that it actually just removes anything to the right of the decimal. This makes a difference when used against a negative number. Also, it will always return a number, and will never give you `NaN`. If it can't be converted to a number, you'll get `0`.

Comment: @Chad - It's probably still faster than `Math.floor()`, which has to look up the Math global object *and* do a function call.

Comment: The test that the article links to has `Math.floor` in the title of the text, but `Math.round` in the code, so that doesn't say anything about the speed of `Math.floor`...

Comment: @Guffa It's a good thing that test page is editable then. :) I just tested it and `~~` was twice as fast as `Math.floor` on Safari 5.

Comment: I ran into an integer overflow issue using this technique with very large numbers (the result of dividing numbers from the Navigation Timing API by 62 during base-62 encoding). For instance, in Firefox, Chrome and IE, ~~(2419354838.709677) == -1875612458, whereas Math.floor(2419354838.709677) == 2419354838.

Comment: @JacobWan Yes, this isn't a browser-dependent matter. Bitwise operations in JS produce signed 32-bit integers, so this should be avoided if there's any chance that the input is greater than 2^31 - 1.

Comment: Similar to Math.trunc(), but not Math.floor()

Comment: Wrong!  It looks like the code example has been through a minifier. It is being used to save space. ~~ is shorter than Math.floor()

Comment: While ~~ is faster alias of Math.floor(), -~ is an alias of Math.ceil()

Comment: It looks like for negative numbers you just switch it around: `-~` becomes `Math.floor()` and `~~` becomes `Math.ceil()`. And here I thought `~~` was just for parsing integer strings...

Comment: `~~` is the equivalent of `parseInt`

Comment: Also to note `Math.floor("str")` gives `NaN` while `Math.floor('')` returns `0` But `~~"str"` and `~~""` would return `0`

Comment: @JunaidAnwar In my testing on Chromium browsers, `~~` is faster even than `Math.trunc()`.

Answer (score 222):

It hides the intention of the code.

It's two single tilde operators, so it does a bitwise complement (bitwise not) twice. The operations take out each other, so the only remaining effect is the conversion that is done before the first operator is applied, i.e. converting the value to an integer number.

Some use it as a faster alternative to `Math.floor`, but the speed difference is not that dramatic, and in most cases it's just micro optimisation. Unless you have a piece of code that really needs to be optimised, you should use code that descibes what it does instead of code that uses a side effect of a non-operation.

#### Update 2011-08:

With optimisation of the JavaScript engine in browsers, the performance for operators and functions change. With current browsers, using `~~` instead of `Math.floor` is somewhat faster in some browsers, and not faster at all in some browsers. If you really need that extra bit of performance, you would need to write different optimised code for each browser.

See: [tilde vs floor](http://jsperf.com/tilde-vs-floor)

Comment: +1 for "it hides the intention of the code", i wasted 10 minutes to know what `~~` does. Anyway I also have to admit it's already strong in me the dark side that's already tempting me to use `~~` in place of `Math.floor` forever in my new code now on. :))))

Comment: Note that micro tests like JSPerf (necessarily) run the test code enough times that on-the-fly runtime optimizations (such as in V8) kick in. That test shows that (if used very heavily) `Math.floor()` _can_ be as fast as `~~` on Chrome, but not that it _is always_ the same speed. These days it's just quite hard to say for sure whether or not one bit of code is "faster" than another (accounting for different browsers and invocation scenarios).

Comment: Why on earth is Chrome 22 so much slower than Chrome 8??

Comment: @MattSach: The figures are only comparable if tested on the same computer, or if plenty enough people have tested it. Chrome has so many versions that there is rarely more than a handful of persons that has tested the code with each version.

Comment: Just remember that Math.floor() exists for a reason. Don't go off using ~~ because it's 2 microseconds faster than Math.floor if you don't understand where it might cause overflows or other unexpected results.

Comment: This gap has narrowed significantly for Chrome. https://jsperf.com/math-floor-vs-math-round-vs-parseint/183

Comment: As mentioned in other comments here, it's not the same as Math.floor.

Comment: If anyone is wondering why there is a single operation of converting it to an integer. Here you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723575/how-to-perform-a-bitwise-operation-on-floating-point-numbers#:~:text=Floating%20point%20numbers%20don't,apply%20bitwise%20operations%20to%20them.

Answer (score 174):

```
~(5.5)   // => -6
~(-6)    // => 5
~~5.5    // => 5  (same as Math.trunc(5.5) and Math.floor(5.5))
~~(-5.5) // => -5 (same as Math.trunc(-5.5) but NOT the same as Math.floor(-5.5), which would give -6 )
```

For more info, see:

- http://dreaminginjavascript.wordpress.com/2008/07/04/28/

Comment: `~(-5.5)` => `4`, `~(4)` => `-5`, `~~(-5.5)` => `-5`. Therefor, not the same as `Math.floor`

Comment: @zzzzBov, I updated the post to clarify that `~~` is not the same as `Math.floor()` for negative numbers.

Comment: Math.floor(-5.5), which would give -6. Bcos Math.floor will return largest integer less than or equal to a given number. Math.floor(-5.00000001) also give -6.

Answer (score 25):

The diffrence is very simple:

**Long version**

If you want to have better readability, use `Math.floor`. But if you want to minimize it, use tilde `~~`.

There are a lot of sources on the internet saying `Math.floor` is faster, but sometimes `~~`. I would not recommend you think about speed because it is not going to be noticed when running the code. Maybe in tests etc, but no human can see a diffrence here. What would be faster is to use `~~` for a faster load time.

**Short version**

`~~` is shorter/takes less space. `Math.floor` improves the readability. Sometimes tilde is faster, sometimes `Math.floor` is faster, but it is not noticeable.

Comment: Right. It's primarily a stylistic choice, like the choice between Boolean(foo), (foo ? true : false), or !!foo when you want to cast a variable to a boolean.

Comment: Math.trunc(), not Math.floor()