# ParseInt() method on array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am wondering to how to get number from an array. I have tried its give me NaN error

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

var Arr = [ 'h78em', 'w145px', 'w13px' ]

alert(parseInt(Arr[0]))


})
</script>
```

Comment: That's because `h78em` is not a number.

Comment: If you just want all the digits in the string you could use a regex: `parseInt(Arr[0].replace(/\D/g), '')`. Do you care about more complex cases like `abc123def456`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a function that builds the number from your string:

```
function stringToNum(str){
  num = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < str.length; i++) 
    if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9') 
      num = num * 10 + parseInt(str[i]);
  return num;
}
```

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/8WwHh/

Comment: Wow!, Can you please tell what is the logic behind it

Comment: you start with num = 0, and iterate the characters from the string. If you find a digit, you multiply your number with 10 and add the new digit at the end.

Comment: What to do with `stringToNum('123abc345def')`?

Comment: It depends: would you like to see the values as separate numbers, or as a single number? The latter case is what your method covers, but for the first case your method wouldn't be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

try with

```
+Arr[0].replace(/\D/g, '');
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t6yCV/

Starting `+` is working like `parseInt()` and it is necessary if you need to perform some mathematical operation with the number obtained: in fact

```
typeof Arr[0].replace(/\D/g,'')  // String
typeof +Arr[0].replace(/\D/g,'') // Number
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
['h78em', 'w145px', 'w13px']
 .map(function(a){return ~~(a.replace(/\D/g,''));});
 //=> [78, 145, 13]
```

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971645/what-is-the-double-tilde-operator-in-javascript)

Or use a somewhat more elaborate `String` prototype extension:

```
String.prototype.intsFromString = function(combine){
 var nums = this.match(/\d{1,}/g);
 return !nums ? 0 
         : nums.length>1 ? combine ? ~~nums.join('') 
           : nums.map(function(a){return ~~a;}) 
         : ~~nums[0];
};
// usage
'abc23'.intsFromString();          //=> 23
'3abc121cde'.intsFromString();     //=> [3,121]
'3abc121cde'.intsFromString(true); //=> 3121
'abcde'.intsFromString();          //=> 0
// and ofcourse
['h78em', 'w145px', 'w13px'].map(function(a){return a.intsFromString();});
//=> [78, 145, 13]
```

Comment: Nice: just for simplification: `[^\d] ==> \D` - and unfortunately IE8 doesn't support `map`

Comment: @Fabrizio: yep, adjusted. You can find a `Array.prototype.map` shim @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var Arr = [ 'h78em', 'w145px', 'w13px' ]

function stringToNum(str){
  return str.match(/\d+/g);

}

alert(stringToNum(Arr[0]));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8WwHh/1/

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
alert(parseInt(Arr[0].replace(/[a-z_A-Z]/g,"")));
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucDxd/1/)

Comment: Mind for case sensitiveness. Also, this would make something like "a52eb2" in 522. Not sure if that is correct, you might end up with a different number.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another quick and dirty solution:

```
alert(Arr[0].match("\\d+"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it,this regex is better

```
parseInt('h343px'.replace(/^[a-zA-Z]+/,''),10)
```

Comment: Try `parseInt('{h343px}'.replace(/^[a-zA-Z]+/,''),10)`?