# Why it is leaving the decimals

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the “double tilde” (~~) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971645/what-is-the-double-tilde-operator-in-javascript)

My Code:

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript"> 

var num = 2.52;
alert(~~num);

</SCRIPT>
```

It is giving the result as `2`. Why it is leaving the decimals? Any Ideas.

Comment: What else did you expect from an integer?

Comment: The double not (`~~`) bitwise operator will floor a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an explanation http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/double-bitwise-not/

> The bitwise NOT operator (~) will take its operand, convert it to a
>   32-bit integer, and will invert each bit so that each 0 becomes a 1
>   and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I found this helpful resource:

http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/great-mystery-of-the-tilde/

Léon

Answer (score 0):

Every bitwise operation in JavaScript does [convert its arguments to signed 32bit intergers](http://es5.github.com/#x9.5). This will strip of your decimals. Else, you might expect the double [bitwise NOT](http://es5.github.com/#x11.4.8) to yield its argument unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the tildes (~).

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript"> 

var num = 2.52;
alert(num);

</SCRIPT>
```