# What exactly does the Javascript ~~ operator do?

Tags: javascript, operator-keyword

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What is the “double tilde” (~~) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971645/what-is-the-double-tilde-operator-in-javascript)

I was wondering for a time now what exactly the `~~` operator does in javascript.

It seems it does essentially the same as `Math.floor` at least when [looking](http://jsbin.com/ohiyuz/1/edit?javascript&console) at the result.

```
~~(1.2345) //1
Math.floor(1.2345) // 1
```

The other thing is that i don't find anything about it anywhere. *Well, google doesn't let one search for "~~"*

But also when looking at the [ECMA Script Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) i can't seem to find a single entry mentioning `~~`

And running a [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/vs-floor) on both gives a surprising result too. As `Math.floor` is

- Chrome - 1%
- Firefox - 54%
- Internet Explorer - 84%

slower for me than `~~`.

Could anyone please shine a light on this?
Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Google-fu: "double tilde"

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971645/what-is-the-double-tilde-operator-in-javascript

Comment: Nice, thanks for the Link, that was exactly what i was looking for.
Shame on me that i didn't thought of googling "double tilde"