# How to do a bitwise complement of a Double and negate it?

Tags: swift

How do you negate a bitwise complement of a Double in Swift 4?

In particular, I'm trying to convert the following (trvial) javascript line to Swift:

```
var j = -~(0.707 * x);
```

Using it as is gives the error message "Unary operators may not be juxtaposed; parenthesize inner expression".

Ok, I don't like that either.  So, I tried:

```
var j = -(~(0.707 * x))  //Compile error: "Unary operator '~' cannot be applied to an operand of type 'Double'".
```

Then:

```
var j = -(~((0.707 * x).bitPattern))  //Compile error: "Unary operator '-' cannot be applied to an operand of type 'UInt64'".
```

And then:

```
var j = -Int64(~((0.707 * x).bitPattern)))
```

which compiles but crashes with "Fatal error: Not enough bits to represent a signed value"

Eventually, I found myself standing on my head rubbing my belly and sticking pins in a doll bought in Louisiana while sacrificing a frozen chicken.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript implicitly *truncates* a number to the next integral value 
towards zero before applying the bitwise-not operator `~`:

```js
console.log(-~(12.34))    // 13
console.log(-~(-12.34))   // -11
```

Therefore

```
var j = -~(0.707 * x);
```

would be in Swift

```
let j = -(~Int(0.707 * x))
```

or, since negative integers in Swift use a two's complement representation, simply

```
let j = Int(0.707 * x) + 1
```

Examples:

```
print(-(~Int(12.34)))   // 13
print(Int(12.34) + 1)   // 13

print(-(~Int(-12.34)))  // -11
print(Int(-12.34) + 1)  // -11
```

Comment: I always prefer understanding what's going on, but I have to admit, I was confused by the javascript line.  So, if I'm not mistaken, for positive x all it does is round up then truncate?

Comment: @Greg: Almost. It truncates down (towards zero) and then adds 1. For example, for all  numbers 5.0, 5.1, 5.99 the result is 6 (truncated to 5, then +1). For all numbers -4.0, -4.1, -4.99 the result is -3 (truncated to -4, then +1)

Comment: Yes, I misstated that.  Very interesting!  Why would that javascript line not be written like your 2nd print line above?  Is it significantly faster?

Comment: @Greg: Using `~` seems to be a method to truncate a double which is faster than `Math.floor()` (https://stackoverflow.com/q/5971645/1187415). I am not an JavaScript expert, so I cannot judge if that is "good" or not. – If you provide more information (where does that code come from and what is it used for?) then we might figure out how to do the same properly in Swift.

Comment: Thank you, Martin.  No big deal, I was just curious. I always try to optimize things too, but I'm not going to bother with this since it will only run once in a while.
Thank you very much for the help and clarifications!

Answer (score 1):

I guess is not that much complicated:

**Swift**:

```
var result = -Double(bitPattern:~(0.707 * 10.0).bitPattern) // replace 10.0 with x
```

**Javascript**:

```
var j = -~(0.707 * x);
```

I think the most important is the "casting back" from `bitPattern` to `Double`, if you miss that part you may have not only compilation problems but also semantic problems; you may guess you are operating with base 10 numbers, instead you have a mix of base 10 and base 2

---

**edit:**

as Martin said, JS implicitly truncates, so although the above results won't match, I think the Swift solution with `bitPattern` is the most correct