# I have a problem while running the below code, I want to print msg

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to run the code but the error like "Object error comes"

```js
var today= new Date(); 
var hourNow = today.getHours(); 
   
if (hourNow > 18) { 
  console.log("GoodEvening");
}
else if (hourNow > 12) { 
  console.log("GoodAfternoon"); 
}
else if (hourNow > 0) {
  console.log("GoodMorning");
}
```

Comment: its working fine its 10am here and as ur condition its print `Good Morning`

Comment: You need to explain! cause the code that you have posted works fine! do you need something else?

Comment: `Object error comes` what exactly is the error that you get

Comment: I can also confirm that your code is working on my workstation. Can you post the error code?

Answer (score 0):

try below code

### index.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My awesome webpage</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This site is awesome!</h1>
    <p>And I coded it from scratch.</p>
    <div id="disply-date"></div>
    <script>
      var today= new Date(); 
      var hourNow = today.getHours(); 

      if (hourNow > 18) { 
        console.log("GoodEvening");
        document.getElementById("disply-date").innerHTML = "GoodEvening";
      }
      else if (hourNow > 12) { 
        console.log("GoodAfternoon"); 
        document.getElementById("disply-date").innerHTML = "GoodAfternoon";
      }
      else if (hourNow > 0) {
        console.log("GoodMorning");
        document.getElementById("disply-date").innerHTML = "GoodMorning";
      }
    </scirpt>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(["Good Morning", "Good Afternoon", "Good Evening"][~~(new Date().getHours() / 8)]);
```

**Code Golf!**

How this works:

You don't need to create a new Date object and stash it in a variable if you are just getting the hours. So you can do: `new Date().getHours()`.

It also turns out, that you can place your messages in an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/array) and select the message you want like:  `var arr = ["Good Morning", "Good Afternoon", "Good Evening"]; console.log(arr[2]);`. But you don't need to stash the array in a variable to get the message. You can do this: `["Good Morning", "Good Afternoon", "Good Evening"][2]`. Sure, it looks a little weird, but it's saying, "Hey, here's an array of strings, get me the one at index 2."

So how to get the hours and turn it into 0, 1 or 2 (our indexes)? Well, take the hours and divide by 8. That will get you close. Say it's 7:30 am. You take 7 / 8 and get 0.875. That isn't an index. We need to round down. So we can do `Math.floor(7/8)` and we get 0.

We can feed THAT (`0`) to our array and get `Good Morning`. Cool. `Math.floor` is too many characters to type and I'm lazy. There's a Javascript hack using bitwise operators explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971645/what-is-the-double-tilde-operator-in-javascript/5971668). Basically `~~` does a `Math.floor`. So we can cheat and do `~~(new Date().getHours() / 8)` to turn the hours into `0`, `1`, or `2`.

Take that result, get our string out of our array and smash the entire thing into console.log.