# Creating an array of objects with random number of properties

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create an array of objects that will be populated by random properties.
I want the objects all to look like this

`{ systemStar: "something random", planets: ["random1", "random2", etc]}`
Currently I have the following code

```
const letThereBeLight = () => {
  let universe = []
  const starNumber = 5;
  let randomNumberOfPlanets = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  for (let i = 0; i < starNumber; i++) {
    universe.push({
      systemStar: starList[Math.floor(Math.random() * lengthOfStarList)],
      systemPlanets: [planetList[Math.floor(Math.random() * lengthOfPlanetList)]]
    })

  }

  console.log(universe)
}
```

This does a great job in creating the objects I want with the following format, however the `systemPlanets` is only one, instead of a random number. I have tried to do a double for loop but the syntax was eluding me.
How can I get an array of random strings inside of my for loop?

Added variables for clarity

```
let starList = [
  "Red-Giant",
  "Red-Supergiant",
  "Blue-Giant",
  "White-Dwarf",
  "Yellow-Dwarf",
  "Red-Dwarf",
  "Brown-Dwarf",
];
let planetList = [
  "Rocky",
  "Temperate",
  "Ocean",
  "Frozen",
  "Lava",
  "Gas"
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Array.from({length:5})` to create an array of 5 elements.
and replace `5` with a random number by using `Math.random() * 5` `Math.floor()` method to round it down to near number, add add one to at least create one planet. then `map` them to values in source array `planetList.

```js
let starList = [
  "Red-Giant",
  "Red-Supergiant",
  "Blue-Giant",
  "White-Dwarf",
  "Yellow-Dwarf",
  "Red-Dwarf",
  "Brown-Dwarf",
];
let planetList = [
  "Rocky",
  "Temperate",
  "Ocean",
  "Frozen",
  "Lava",
  "Gas"
];
let lengthOfStarList = starList.length;
let lengthOfPlanetList = planetList.length;
let universe = []
const starNumber = 5;
for (let i = 0; i < starNumber; i++) {
    universe.push({
      systemStar: starList[Math.floor(Math.random() * lengthOfStarList)],
      systemPlanets: Array.from({length:Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)+1}).map(x=>planetList[Math.floor(Math.random() * lengthOfPlanetList)])
    })
}
console.log(universe)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is create another loop of random number that is less than number of available planets, and create an array of planets in that loop:

```js
let starList = [
  "Red-Giant",
  "Red-Supergiant",
  "Blue-Giant",
  "White-Dwarf",
  "Yellow-Dwarf",
  "Red-Dwarf",
  "Brown-Dwarf",
];
let planetList = [
  "Rocky",
  "Temperate",
  "Ocean",
  "Frozen",
  "Lava",
  "Gas"
];

const letThereBeLight = () => {
  let universe = []
  const starNumber = 5;
  let randomNumberOfPlanets = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  for (let i = 0; i < starNumber; i++) {
    const planets = [];
    // generate list of planets with at least 1 planet
    for(let p = 0, max = ~~(Math.random() * planetList.length - 1) + 1; p < max; p++)
      planets[planets.length] = planetList[~~(Math.random() * planetList.length)];

    universe.push({
      systemStar: starList[Math.floor(Math.random() * starList.length)],
      systemPlanets: planets
    })

  }

  console.log(universe)
}
letThereBeLight();
```

Comment: arguably a system could have multiple rocky planets?

Comment: what does `~~` mean?

Comment: see: [What is the "double tilde" (~~) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971645/what-is-the-double-tilde-operator-in-javascript) (Keep using `Math.floor` for readability.)

Comment: @TAHERElMehdi it's a faster version of `Math.floor()`, in cases where only positive number is need, it's a faster substite.