# Check for NaN, null and >=0 in one condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a var a;

Its value can be `NaN, null and any +ve/-ve number including 0.`

I require a condition which filters out all the values of a such that only >=0 values yield a true in if condition.

What is the best possible way to achieve this, I do not wish to use 3 different conditions joined using `||`

Comment: Are you trying to filter nan, null, undefined and 0 values out ?

Comment: yes ...so that if is true only when a != Nan && a!= null and a >=0

Comment: "I do not wish to use 3 different conditions joined using ``||``" - are you ok with ``&&`` then ? What about ``+`` ? What's the purpose of such an artificial limitation ?

Comment: @Iqc - Actually i was looking for only one condition if possible ... but i guess that is not possible ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ohk ...But i actually found the ans ..
it is so Simple .

parseInt(null) = NaN.

So `if(parseInt(a)>=0){}` would do  ...Yayyee

Comment: Yes, but this also allows numeric strings like `"123"`.

Comment: That is ohk in my case .. :)

Answer (score 11):

```
typeof x == "number" && x >= 0
```

This works as follows:

- **`null`** -- `typeof null == "object"` so first part of expression returns false
- **`NaN`** -- `typeof NaN == "number"` but `NaN` is not greater than, less than or equal to any number including itself so second part of expression returns false
- **`number`** -- any other `number` greater than or equal to zero the expression returns true

Comment: I don't think using `typeof` is as efficient as just checking `x !== null`

Comment: NaN !== null returns true. that's what OP is trying to avoid.

Comment: typeof Infinity = 'number'

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work well:

```
if (parseFloat(x) === Math.sqrt(x*x))...
```

Test:

```
isPositive = function(x) { return parseFloat(x) === Math.sqrt(x*x) }
a = [null, +"xx", -100, 0, 100]
a.forEach(function(x) { console.log(x, isPositive(x))})
```

Answer (score 1):

`NaN` is not `>= 0`, so the only exclusion you need to make is for `null`:

```
if (a !== null && a >= 0) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is there any possible way to have one condition and no conjunction(&&)

Comment: @BhumiSinghal not that I know of, since you require a 0 or positive answer and none of the tests for `null` will check the sign of the number.

Comment: No. Simply because you are asking two types of question: 1. Does a have a value? 2. What is the value of a?

Comment: This will be true if x is Infinity and I doubt the OP or most others want to accept that value

Answer (score 1):

My best solution to filter those values out would be with 2 condition and it is like;

```
 if(a!=undefined && a>=0){
      console.log('My variable is filtered out.')
    }
```

I am not sure but there is no single condition usage to make it.

Comment: fails to deny negative numbers

Comment: actually this will be false in case of a ==0 . Thus cant use this.

Comment: Yes I see. I missed something in the question. I'm sorry but as I know there is no way to do with single condition.

Comment: and still fails to deny negative numbers

Comment: yes ..now this is a valid condition ...I see i will have to use two conditions in the least

Comment: This does not break the conditions.Because  `null!=undefined` is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem some weeks ago, I solved it with:

```
if(~~Number(test1)>0) {
  //...
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pT7pp/2/

Comment: Nice! (as long as their numbers stay in the 32-bit range)

Comment: can u please explain this ?

Comment: Are you sure? I thought JavaScript represents numbers in double-precision (64 bit) format using IEEE-754?

Comment: I hope it's okay to send two links for explain:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055633/what-does-do-in-javascript
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971645/what-is-the-double-tilde-operator-in-javascript

Comment: @RobSky: yes, but bitwise operators (& | ~ ^) always convert their arguments to int32's.

Comment: This will cast `null` to zero then check for `>= 0` which is not desired.

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged jQuery, take a look at [`$.isNumeric()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/)

```
if($.isNumeric(a) && a >= 0)
```

Comment: Please don't use that! "$.isNumeric("-10"); // true" - that's never a good idea.

Comment: Since this function only do a basic `return !isNaN( parseFloat(obj) ) && isFinite( obj );`, I don't understand this statement.

Comment: @lqc Plus, the OP statued that `a` could only be `NaN`, `null` or a `number`.

Comment: So if you know it's a number, why feed it to a parseFloat() under the covers? Also, you throw away ``+Inf``, which is a valid positive number.

Comment: @lqc I didn't statuate that *this* is the best answer (I don't think it is) but just to give a jQuery alternative. `parseFloat` validate both Integer and Float (in this case) which are Numbers. But, fair enough for `+Inf` (still I doubt he'll use it ;))