# How to differentiate null and zero value for variable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to check the value is null and zero in java script

```
var result;
if(result!==null)
```

I had tried
please specify to check whether the value is zero

Comment: And also for undefined variable check

Comment: how to check variable value is not defined and null in java script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine if variable is 'undefined' or 'null'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647867/how-to-determine-if-variable-is-undefined-or-null)

Comment: For checking value iszero when variable is defined

Comment: @Naveenkumar then use `=== 0`

Comment: I can use === 0 or >== 0 in vue js

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use something like

```
if((x >= 0) && (typeof(result) == "number"))
```

Seems to have been answered here ::: [Check for NaN, null and >=0 in one condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16477405/check-for-nan-null-and-0-in-one-condition)

Comment: In vue Js how to specify condition for >= and ==

Comment: @Naveenkumar This was not specified in the original question.

Comment: For vue Js how to specify condition

Comment: @Naveenkumar Vue.js is a *JavaScript* framework, you can thus use *JavaScript* to specify conditions.

Comment: which is best x !== null or x != null for verifying not defined and null value

Comment: @Naveenkumar See the duplicate question.