# What Is '~ ~' in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Have seen '~ ~' can someone explain what it is used for?

Have done google searchs and nothing is returning for this.

It is some math operator but don't know what it is actually doing to numeric values?

Comment: if this is a duplicate what am i suppose to do which the q & a's?

Comment: Not sure where this is a duplicate. I don't see any previous questions. Link?

Comment: i see it as marked as duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055633/what-does-do-in-javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

~ is a bitwise operator. By using it twice, some people say its an optimization instead of using `Math.floor` like:

`var a = 1.9;`
`Math.floor(a) === ~~a // true (1 === 1)`

**However 1)** Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5971774/949346) to understand how is it achieved, and [this performance test](http://jsperf.com/tilde-vs-floor) to see that in some cases the `Math.floor()` is faster. It does make sense that `Math.floor()` will outperform later on, because that is its purpose!

**However 2)** Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4055675/949346) to see the different effect on negative numbers and some edge cases.

`var a = -1.5;`
`Math.floor(a) !== ~~a // true (-2 !== -1)`

**However +)**
`Math.floor(Infinity) !== ~~Infinity // true (Infinity !== 0)`

**However ++)**
Check the comments as well, I'm sure there will be some more interesting aspects.

Personally I prefer readability in such case where the performance is not even a sure thing. Plus the other effects ... just use `Math.floor` it's for the best!

See for more bitwise operators: [mozzila ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators), and how numbers are represented in JavaScript on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_number.asp).

Comment: Not quite the same as `Math.floor()`, as the JavaScript bitwise operators all work with 32-bit values. `Math.floor` can deal with 64-bit floating point values.

Comment: Also, `~~"a"` returns 0, while `Math.floor("a")` is NaN.

Answer (score 3):

It's a pair of bitwise complement operators. It's not a single operator.

It's sometimes used to coerce a numeric value to be a 32-bit integer:

```
var anInteger = ~ ~ aValue;
```