# Grunt Contrib JSHint Warnings

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-jshint

So in our build, we use jshint to warn us of any console log errors and any other anomalies. Currently, I'm unable to build (without --force) whenever I'm using the bitwise ~ operator. I am getting the following error in verbose:

```
>> Line 310: Unexpected '~'.
>> totalImpressions += ~~(data[i].impressions);
```

I added the

```
/*jshint bitwise:false */
```

flag in the top of the config file, but to no avail.

I also tried adding an ignore_warnings object like so:

```
/* global module */
/* Created by frank on 3/4/14. */
/*jshint bitwise:false */
module.exports = {
    options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        ignores: [],
        ignore_warning: {
            options: {
                '-W018': true,
                '-W052': true
            },
            src: ['**/*.js']
        }
    },
    all: []
}
```

But I have emptied out the strings in ignores and all for privacy...
If anyone knows how to supress this error, I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: If `data[i].impressions` are positive numbers, [can you just use `Math.floor` instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5971689/1377002)?

Comment: sometimes they're not.

Comment: [Can you use this function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4055675/1377002)?