# How to generate random color for JSCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, jscharts

```
function getRandomColor() {
            var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
            var color = '#';
            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
            } 
            return color;
        }
```

I'm using JSCharts in a project I'm working on and I need a different color for each bar in a Graph/Bar Chart.

the below example works fine but if I have more than 6 records then it alert me a message:

> JSChart" Colors array length must equal data length in case of pie and
>   bar graphs

How can I generate color based on the number of records?

Here's an example of the bar chart data set:

```
$.getJSON("http://...", function (data) {

        var array = $.map(data, function (data) {
            return [[data.Name, parseInt(data.Id)]];
        }); 

        var colors = ['#FA5E1F', '#FDCB3F', '#71D743', '#D23333', '#BAE73F', '#B381C9'];
        var myChart = new JSChart('graph', 'bar');
        myChart.setDataArray(array);
        myChart.colorizeBars(colors);
        myChart.setTitle('Title');
        myChart.setTitleColor('#8E8E8E');
        myChart.setAxisNameX('Orgs');
        myChart.setAxisNameY('%');
        myChart.setAxisColor('#c6c6c6');
        myChart.setAxisWidth(1);
        myChart.setAxisNameColor('#9a9a9a');
        myChart.setAxisValuesColor('#939393');
        myChart.setAxisPaddingTop(60);
        myChart.setAxisPaddingLeft(50);
        myChart.setAxisPaddingBottom(60);
        myChart.setTextPaddingBottom(20);
        myChart.setTextPaddingLeft(15);
        myChart.setTitleFontSize(11);
        myChart.setBarBorderWidth(0);
        myChart.setBarSpacingRatio(50);
        myChart.setBarValuesColor('#737373');
        myChart.setGrid(false);
        myChart.setSize(616, 321);
        //myChart.setBackgroundImage('chart_bg.jpg');
        myChart.draw();
    });
```

Comment: Have you tried to make a function that generates colors? Think about what you know. You will need to generate 6 hexadecimal values or 3 integers that are less than 256. I'd love to help but it seems like you didn't even attempt to solve it yourself.

Comment: okay, updated my question there two problems so the function i wrote 1) i have to pass number of counts 2) i am not returning an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function looks good! To use it to generate colors in an array, just use a loop:

```
function getColorArray(num) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < num; i += 1) {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
        var color = '#';
        for (var j = 0; j < 6; j += 1) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        result.push(color);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then, you can get your data length by using the `Array.length` property. Replace these lines:

```
var colors = ['#FA5E1F', '#FDCB3F', '#71D743', '#D23333', '#BAE73F', '#B381C9'];
var myChart = new JSChart('graph', 'bar');
myChart.setDataArray(array);
myChart.colorizeBars(colors);
```

with:

```
var myChart = new JSChart('graph', 'bar');
myChart.setDataArray(array);
myChart.colorizeBars(getColorArray(array.length));
```

Comment: Thanks, the `getColorArray` is not returning a set of arrays, its just returning only the last one, when i debug.

Comment: in the cosole.debug I'm getting the last color without an array colors `["#9BB08E"]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use bitwise operators to generate random hex colors:

```
var getRandomColor = function () {
    var random = Math.random();
    var exponent = --random.toExponential().split('-')[1];

    random *= Math.pow(10, exponent);

    return '#' + ( ~~(random * (1 << 24) )).toString(16);
};
```

Then you can use your `data` array to determine the amount of colors:

```
// Example data Array.
var data = [ 1, 2, 4, 5, 6];

// The amount of random colors you want to generate.
var amount = data.length;
```

Now you can create a loop and generate your colors and push them in a `colors` Array:

```
// Will contain the random hex colors.
var colors = [];

// Generate colors.
while(amount--) {
    colors.push(getRandomColor());
}
```

Whats going on in `getRandomColor()`:

The 'highest' hex value is `ffffff` and the 'lowest' is `000000`, when converting these to decimal numbers you get:

```
parseInt('ffffff', 16); // 16777215
parseInt('000000', 16); // 0
```

It turns out, `2^24` equals `16777216`, this can be calculated using the [bitwise left shift operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Left_shift), i.e, `1 << n` shifts the operand `n` bits to the left which equals `2^n`. Therefore `1 << 24` equals `16777216`.

This means that as long as you can provide a random number between `1` and `0.1` to multiply it with `1 << 24`, you'll always get a valid hex value.

To assure this, you need to extract the exponent from `Math.random()`, because it can also return values like `0.0088248689007014`. If you wouldn't do this, you will NOT get correct hex values all the time.

Finally before converting the random number to a hex value, you can use the `~~` double [bitwise not operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Bitwise_NOT) to remove everything after the decimal point.

You can find more info on the double bitwise operator [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055633/what-does-double-tilde-do-in-javascript)