# Unable to receive a non decimal place number from Nashorn engine after rounding

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I have a problem related to the Numbers with Nashorn engine

Core problem is unable to receive a non decimal place number from Nashorn engine after rounding it using `Math.round()`.

But it returns values with decimal places although within js it provides without decimal places and when I just return the harcoded primitive, it works fine.

How can I need to convert the floating point value to it's closest integer and receive it through the Nashorn. I know I can simply do `return (num+"")`;. But I like to do it nicer and learn some new thing.
Note : I want to do this with the js function.

**script.js**

```
var nonMath = function(){
    var num = 2; 
    print("num : " + num); //prints 2
    return (num);
};

var doMath = function(){
    var num = Math.round(2.0); 
    print("num : " + num); //prints 2
    return (num);
};
```

**TestClass.java**

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
engine.eval(new FileReader("lib/script.js"));

Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;
System.out.println("nonMath : " + invocable.invokeFunction("nonMath")); //prints 2
System.out.println("doMath : " + invocable.invokeFunction("doMath")); //prints 2.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`~~`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055633/what-does-double-tilde-do-in-javascript) to truncate the result of `Math.round` like

```
var doMath = function(){
    var num = ~~Math.round(2.0);
    return num;
}
```

which I ran with your code to get

```
doMath : 2
```

Comment: That works Thank you Elliott! Thanks you for the link too.