# Is it OK tu use ~~ to get the integer part of a number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, unary-operator

It seems to yield what I am looking for but I'm wondering if it could possibly induce strange bugs or have undesired behavior.
Thank you.

Comment: For information, you may want to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055633/what-does-double-tilde-do-in-javascript

Comment: It will definitely introduce some WTF's. Just use regular `Math.floor`. **Explicit is better than implicit.**

Comment: Thank you @DavidThomas, I found what I needed in your link !

Comment: @KamilLatosinski Math.floor doesn't return the entire part for negative numbers. Thanks anyway, your true about explicitness.