# Add class randomly to only one of two divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two divs and I want to add the class ".active" to only one of them at random.

This is the best I could come up with, however, sometimes both divs get the class added.

```
randomClass: function(){
        var classes = ["active", ""];
         $(".contain > div").each(function(){
           $(this).addClass(classes[~~(Math.random()*classes.length)]);
        });
    },
```

HTML

```
 <div class="contain">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: For those that don't know that the double tilde does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055633/what-does-double-tilde-do-in-javascript

Comment: you can get an array of div inside .contain div and use math random for random index in that array to add class active to div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote the following code to use the eq.  It will select a random number between the valid indexes and then return that value and then append the proper class.  I added one line to remove whichever one currently has the class active, so the button would work.

**Important logic error with your code**: by using .each you are **not** guaranteeing that both or none are not selected.  You have to select the object before hand.

**With your code**, here is the possible out comes (where 1 is active and 0 is not active):

```
1 0
0 1
1 1
0 0
```

There is a **50%** chance your code will not work as intended.

So, I wrote mine a little differently.

```js
function randomClass(){
 $(".contain > div").removeClass("active");
 $(".contain > div").eq(Math.floor(Math.random()*$(".contain > div").length)).addClass("active");
}


randomClass();
```

```css
.active {
 background-color:red;
}
.box {
 width:50px;
 height:50px;
 border:1px solid black;
 margin:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contain">
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<button onclick="randomClass()">New Random</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The eisiest way based on your code:

```
randomClass: function(){
        var classes = ["active", ""];
         $(".contain > div").each(function(){
            var random = Math.random();
            var classesLength = classes.length;
            var index = ~~(random*classesLength);
            index = index <= classesLength - 1 ? index : index -1;
            $(this).addClass(classes.splice(index, 1)[0]);
        });
    },
```

You can add different numbers of your class list and classes will never repeat if it will be unique in array `classes`

Comment: Using this the classes seems to be added to the second div every time.

Comment: @SpencerPope I add fixed version that works perfectly with any count of classes and divs with condition: `classes.length >= divs count`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one simple solution to your problem:

```js
// from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Getting_a_random_integer_between_two_values_inclusive
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function randomClass() {
  var className = 'active';
  var elements = $('.contain > div');
  elements.removeClass(className);
  var index = getRandomIntInclusive(0, elements.length - 1);
  elements.eq(index).addClass(className);
}

randomClass();
```

```css
.contain div {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contain">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
 </div>
```