# Floated int get value & fractions in seperate int

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Lets say I have

`const Price = 279.95;`

I want to get out the fraction like below:

```
const value = 279;
const fraction = 95;
```

How would I accomplish this? Fraction should always be 2 decimals.

Answer (score 1):

You can `split` by `.` after converting the number to *String*

```
var getItems = ( num ) => String(num).split(".");
var splitNum = ( num ) => ( items = getItems( num ), { integer : Number(items[0]), fraction : Number(items[1] || 0) } );
console.log( splitNum( 279.95 ) );
```

**Demo**

```js
var getItems = ( num ) => String(num).split(".");
var splitNum = ( num ) => ( items = getItems( num ), { integer : Number(items[0]), fraction : Number(items[1] || 0) } );

console.log( splitNum( 279.95 ) );

console.log( splitNum( 279 ) );
```

Comment: If the input doesn't contain a decimal, `fraction` will be set to `NaN`. Essentially: `Number(undefined)`

Comment: @SReject Sure, fixed that part as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using a simple math,

```js
const Price = 279.95;
const value = ~~Price;
const fraction = ~~Math.ceil(((Price - value) * 100));

console.log(value); // 279 
console.log(fraction); // 95
```

You can get more information about `~~` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055633/what-does-double-tilde-do-in-javascript).

Comment: Your fraction part might come out to be 94 too, if I am not wrong

Comment: Agree. It returns 94

Comment: @ParijatPurohit We can't guarantee the floating points accuracy. If we need it to be accurate then we have to use  `ceil`.

Comment: @Codehiker You can get accurate results now. See the update.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `Math.round` instead and it will deal with both upper and lower cases

Comment: @NickA Using `ceil` would be more relevant here as the error in calculation wont go more than `~0.01`.

Answer (score 0):

For a set number of decimal places:

```js
    const price = 279.95;

    // Double bitwise NOT; Quicker way to do Math.floor(price)
    const value = ~~price;

    // Remove the interger part from the price
    // then multiply by 100 to remove decimal
    const fraction = Math.ceil((price - value) * 100);

    console.log(value, fraction)
```

If you want to support an arbitrary number of decimal places use this to get the `fraction`:

```
// Convert the number to a string
// split the string into an array, delimited by "."
// get the second item(index: 1) from the array
const fraction = String(price).split(".")[1] || 0;
```