# What is the effect of a double negating bitwise operator (~~) - also called "double tilde" - in PHP?

Tags: php, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-not

Refactoring legacy code I have found various occurrences of the following construct:

```
((bool) ~~$field->req ? ' required' : '')
```

According to [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) the Tilde (~) in PHP is the bitwise not, which simple shifts all bits in a variable to their opposite.

If I shift all bits in a variable to their opposite and then shift it back, the variable should be exactly the same as it was before right? So why would somebody do this? Am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure this warrants a downvote. This might explain it, albeit for a different language: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055633/what-does-double-tilde-do-in-javascript

Comment: This does not deserve a downvote, I can't find an answer except for JavaScript too. Found [this link](https://j11y.io/cool-stuff/double-bitwise-not/) if it helps

Comment: Bottom line: `(bool) 0.123` returns true, `(bool) ~~0.123` returns false.

Comment: @Ivar Is right! And why is that?

Comment: For the same reason why that works in JavaScript. See the link in nickb's comment.

Comment: Ok I think I understand from the JavaScript explanations. So the last thing I wonder about what the advantage in this boolean context is. It is already clear that the shifting makes a difference.

Comment: *"also called “double tilde”"* -- who is calling it this way? Post an official reference if there is one.

Comment: @axiac Wikipedia might not be an official reference but indicates that a semantic term is widely accepted: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_tilde. `Double tilde may refer to: Double binary NOT operator`

Comment: Wikipedia says *"Used in languages like JavaScript and PHP as a quick way to cast variable as integer."* but at least about PHP it is completely wrong: https://3v4l.org/jpdfs

Comment: To me, the `~~` in the code you posted is a no-op (as you also said in the question). I guess the original coder mistaken `!` with `~` then added `(bool)` in front of it to get the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `!!` (it converts the value to a boolean) but it is not needed at all. I guess the original coder mistaken `~` for `!` then they added `(bool)` in front of it to achieve the desired result (because, as you noticed in the question, `~~` is a no-op).

The [ternary operator (`?:`)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) forces the evaluation of its first argument as boolean.

The [boolean value](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) of `$field->req` is the same as of `!! $field->req` and `(bool) ~~$field->req` (and `(bool)$field->req` btw).

I would remove the `(bool) ~~` part completely to get smaller and cleaner code.

*Edit by questioner*: **The only effect of ~~ in PHP is to cut of decimals from a float value**.

See the following results:

```
$a = 2.123;
$b = -2.123;
$c = new stdClass();
$d = ["a",2,"c"];
$e = "lord";
$f = -3;
$g = false;
$h = null;
$j = -2.99;
$k = 2.99;


var_dump(~~$a);
var_dump(~~$b);
// var_dump(~~$c); // error
// var_dump(~~$d); // error
var_dump(~~$e);
var_dump(~~$f);
// var_dump(~~$g); // error
// var_dump(~~$h); // error
var_dump(~~$j);
var_dump(~~$k);

var_dump(!!$a);
var_dump(!!$b);
var_dump(!!$c);
var_dump(!!$d);
var_dump(!!$e);
var_dump(!!$f);
var_dump(!!$g);
var_dump(!!$h);
var_dump(!!$j);
var_dump(!!$k);
```

> int(2)  int(-2)  string(4)  "lord"  int(-3)  int(-2)  int(2) 
>   bool(true)  bool(true)  bool(true)  bool(true)  bool(true)  bool(true)
>   bool(false)  bool(false)  bool(true)  bool(true)

Comment: @Blackbam you know that you can post the addition as a separate answer (and maybe get some votes for it ;-) )

Comment: Sure but you brought up the keypoints therefore I think it should be your votes 