# get input value with math function in variable

Tags: javascript

I've got some javascript to change the input value via plus/minus buttons.
I now need to save the value after the value has been decremented in a variable and output it as a number.

The javascript for the decrement looks something like this:

```
if (!isNaN(currentVal) && currentVal > 0) {
    // Decrement one
    $('input[id='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1);
    var test = parseInt($('input[id='+fieldName+']').val(currentVal - 1).val());
    alert(test);
}
```

So as you can see I'm trying to get the updated value of the input in a variable called 'test', but all I'm getting is a NaN. Any ideas how to output the updated value of the input as a number within my test variable?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Could you add concrete values for `fieldName` and `currentVal` and add the corresponding HTML?

Comment: The variable you are calling parseInt on must be incorrect, possibly undefined.

Answer (score 1):

As **@trincot** said we cannot re-produce your situation. But the reason a NaN would be returned is because.

`parseInt` Returns an integer number parsed from the given string. If the first character cannot be converted to a number, **NaN** is returned.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

```js
let a = '1'
let b = 'Two'

console.log(parseInt(a));
// 1
console.log(parseInt(b));
// NaN
console.log(parseInt(undefined))
// NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use double Tilda operator [`~~`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4055675/5066625) which behaves like `Math.floor()` except will return you `0` if the value is not a number.

I believe this is the solution you are looking for:

```js
let inputField = document.querySelector('input[name="fieldName"]');


increment = () => {
  let currentValue = ~~inputField.value;
  alert(currentValue);
  inputField.value = currentValue + 1;
};

decrement = () => {
  let currentValue = ~~inputField.value;
  alert(currentValue);
  if (currentValue > 0) {
    inputField.value = currentValue - 1;
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="number" name="fieldName" value="0" />
<button onclick="increment()">+</button>
<button onclick="decrement()">-</button>
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Something showed up to me.

You are using jquery (I think it's right cause of the $ selector), and you are getting the ID with bracket notation.
Why not using something like

var selector = '#' + fieldName;

Then

$(selector)???

Another thing, usually when I'm trying something with javascript, I try it into the developer tool's console of my browser. 
Doing it step by step avoid mistakes