# Rounding up to 2 decimal places in C#

Tags: c#, math

I have a decimal number which can be like the following:

> 189.182

I want to round this *up* to 2 decimal places, so the output would be the following:

> 189.19

Is there built in functionality for this in the Math class, or something else? I know the ceiling function exists but this doesn't seem to do what I want - it'll round to the nearest int, so just '189' in this case.

Comment: Why marked as duplicate? OP asks to round up, other question asks to round down.

Comment: Without leaving decimal type:

        `public static decimal RoundUp(decimal input, int places)
        {
            if (places < 0) return input; 

            decimal multiplier = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < places; ++i)            
                multiplier *= 10;
            
            return (Math.Ceiling(input * multiplier) / multiplier);
        }`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Multiply by 100, call ceiling, divide by 100 does what I think you are asking for

```
public static double RoundUp(double input, int places)
{
    double multiplier = Math.Pow(10, Convert.ToDouble(places));
    return Math.Ceiling(input * multiplier) / multiplier;
}
```

Usage would look like:

```
RoundUp(189.182, 2);
```

This works by shifting the decimal point right 2 places (so it is to the right of the last 8) then performing the ceiling operation, then shifting the decimal point back to its original position.

Comment: This solution is technically incorrect. A double value has a mantissa and an exponent, and the exponent is of base 2, not base 10. Multiplying a double by 10 or 100 does not simply move a decimal point. The result after multiplication has a different bit pattern. That result may not fit in the mantissa with full precision as a binary number and may end up being truncated, in which case the last significant bit ends up being rounded based on some rules.

Comment: but for a number like `189.182` you should be pretty safe. perhaps should case to a decimal?

Comment: Simple case where this fails for decimal https://dotnetfiddle.net/6IeRVG Input 283.79, output 283.8

Comment: Please pay attention to the warnings above.  This method does produce unexpected results for certain numbers.

Answer (score 37):

You can use:

```
decimal n = 189.182M;
n = System.Math.Ceiling (n * 100) / 100;
```

An explanation of the various rounding functions can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14/whats-the-difference-between-math-floor-and-math-truncate-in-net/580252#580252).

---

Be aware that formulae like this are still constrained by the limited precision of the `double` type,  should that be the type you are using (your question stated decimal but it's possible you may just have meant a floating point value with fractional component rather than that *specific* type).

For example:

```
double n = 283.79;
n = System.Math.Ceiling (n * 100);
```

will actually give you `28380`, not the `283.79` you would expect<sup>(a)</sup>.

If you want accuarate results across the board, you should *definitely* be using the `decimal` type.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> This is because the most accurate IEEE754 double precision representation of `283.79` is *actually:*

```
 283.790000000000020463630789891
```

That extra (admittedly minuscule) fractional component beyond the `.79` gets ceilinged up, meaning it will give you a value higher than you would expect.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as the current accepted answer does not address important floating point precision issues.

Comment: 99.10 х 403.6326

get 40000
expected 39999.99

Answer (score 10):

In .NET Core 3.0 and later versions, three additional rounding strategies are available through the MidpointRounding enumeration.
Besides `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` and `MidpointRounding.ToEven` it now includes:

```cs
 1. MidpointRounding.ToNegativeInfinity
 2. MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity
 3. MidpointRounding.ToZero
```

For this specific question you need to use `MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity`, this will round the number up always.
Note this only works if the number isn't negative. See table below for examples.

| Original number | ToNegativeInfinity | ToPositiveInfinity | ToZero |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3.55 | 3.5 | 3.6 | 3.5 |
| 2.83 | 2.8 | 2.9 | 2.8 |
| 2.54 | 2.5 | 2.6 | 2.5 |
| 2.16 | 2.1 | 2.2 | 2.1 |
| -2.16 | -2.2 | -2.1 | -2.1 |
| -2.54 | -2.6 | -2.5 | -2.5 |
| -2.83 | -2.9 | -2.8 | -2.8 |
| -3.55 | -3.6 | -3.5 | -3.5 |

For more information about midpointrounding see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.midpointrounding

And of course the code to make it work:

```cs
// function explained: Math.Round(number, amount of decimals, MidpointRounding);
decimal number = 189.182m;
number =  Math.Round(number, 2, MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity);
// result: number = 189.19
```

Answer (score 5):

```
            var numberToBeRound1 = 4.125;
            var numberToBeRound2 = 4.175;
            var numberToBeRound3 = 4.631;
            var numberToBeRound4 = 4.638;
            var numberOfDecimalPlaces = 2;
            var multiplier = Math.Pow(10, numberOfDecimalPlaces);

            //To Round Up => 4.13
            var roundedUpNumber = Math.Ceiling(numberToBeRound1 * multiplier) / multiplier;

            //To Round Down => 4.12
            var roundedDownNumber = Math.Floor(numberToBeRound1 * multiplier) / multiplier;

            //To Round To Even => 4.12
            var roundedDownToEvenNumber = Math.Round(numberToBeRound1, numberOfDecimalPlaces, MidpointRounding.ToEven);

            //To Round To Even => 4.18
            var roundedUpToEvenNumber = Math.Round(numberToBeRound2, numberOfDecimalPlaces, MidpointRounding.ToEven);

            //To Round To Away From Zero => 4.63
            var roundedDownToAwayFromZero = Math.Round(numberToBeRound3, numberOfDecimalPlaces, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);

            //To Round To Away From Zero => 4.64
            var roundedUpToAwayFromZero2 = Math.Round(numberToBeRound4, numberOfDecimalPlaces, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Comment: I didn't notice question old is but i've tried to be crystal clear

Comment: Don't to Pow guys, be like Furkan!

Comment: `Math.Round(number, decimalPlaces, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);`

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
0.01 * ceil(100 * 189.182)
```

Comment: awesome, just what I needed. I dont know why but Math.ceil(189.182 * 100) / 100 doesnt work....

Comment: Just want to add for anyone else who comes across this that to get more or less decimal places adjust the number of zeros in the constants - 3 decimal places is 0.001 * ceil(1000 * n) 4 is 0.0001 * ceil(10000 * n) and so on

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static decimal RoundUp(decimal input, int places)
    {
        decimal multiplier = (decimal)Math.Pow(10, places);
        return decimal.Ceiling(input * multiplier) / multiplier;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   // Double will return the wrong value for some cases. eg: 160.80
    public static decimal  RoundUp(decimal input, int places)
    {
        decimal multiplier = Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Pow(10, Convert.ToDouble(places)));
        return Math.Ceiling(input * multiplier) / multiplier;
    }
```

Comment: Please always describe what you are doing in your answer. It should be updated or removed. Read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before you provide more answers ^^

Answer (score 0):

One other quirky but fun way to do it is `Math.Round()` after offsetting the number.

```cs
decimal RoundUp(decimal n, int decimals)
{
    n += decimal.Parse($"1e-{decimals}", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowExponent) / 2;
    n -= 1e-28m;
    return Math.Round(n, decimals);
}
```

```cs
decimal RoundDown(decimal n, int decimals)
{
    n -= decimal.Parse($"1e-{decimals}", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowExponent) / 2;
    n += 1e-28m;
    return Math.Round(n, decimals);
}
```

Is has the advantage of not using `Math.Pow()` which uses `double` and thus can cause unpredictable rounding errors.

This solution basically uses the fact that midpoint rounding can be turned into up/down rounding if you increase/decrease the number a little:

- `Math.Round(3.04m, 1)` is `3.0` - not what we want
- Let's add `0.04(9)` to it
- `Math.Round(3.0899999999999999999999999999m, 1)` is `3.1` - success!

Subtracting `1e-28m` (= `0.0000000000000000000000000001`) is important, because we want to be able to round up `3.0000000000000000000000000001` to `4`, but `3.0000000000000000000000000000` should stay `3`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Math.Round(price, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Helped for me

.NET 4.5

Checked calculations:

99.10 х 403.6326 = 39999.99;

2.065 х 277 = 572.01;