# MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero

Tags: c#, .net

Why does below code returns 1299.49 ? According to msdn documentation it should give 1299.5.

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round( 1299.492, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))
```

Comment: What makes you think it should give 1299.5? In what way is 1299.492 the midpoint of 1299.49 and 1299.50?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am still confused here as 1299.492 is somewhere between 1299.49 and 1299.50. So after two decimal rounding it should give me 1299.50 is this correct ? @JonSkeet

Comment: Nope. I suggest you read the docs for `Math.Round` more carefully. In particular: "A parameter specifies how to round the value if it is midway between two numbers." "Somewhere between" isn't the same as "midway between".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be confused as to how this overload works. According to [MSDN on MidpointRounding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When a number is halfway between two others, it is rounded toward the nearest number that is away from zero.

In your case, 1299.492 is not halfway between 1229.49 and 1299.50, so `MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero` doesn't even apply.

---

It looks like what you're actually trying to do is **round up** to the nearest 2 decimal places. In that case, you want something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075201/rounding-up-to-2-decimal-places-in-c-sharp):

```
public static double RoundUp(double input, int places)
{
    double multiplier = Math.Pow(10, Convert.ToDouble(places));
    return Math.Ceiling(input * multiplier) / multiplier;
}
```

This rounds up to the specified decimal places by multiplying by `10^places` (100 if you need 2 places), calling `Math.Ceiling`, and then dividing.

This works:

```
Console.WriteLine(RoundUp(1299.492, 2)); // 1299.5
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am still confused here as 1299.492 is somewhere between  1299.49 and 1299.50. So after two decimal rounding it should give me 1299.50 is this correct ?

Answer (score 4):

You are rounding to 2 decimal places, hence why 1299.49 is returned.

If you want it to be 1299.5, round to 1 decimal place.

```
Console.WriteLine(Math.Round( 1299.492, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))
```

From the documentation about AwayFromZero:

> When a number is halfway between two others, it is rounded toward the nearest number that is away from zero.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I am still confused here as 1299.492 is somewhere between 1299.49 and 1299.50. So after two decimal rounding it should give me 1299.50 is this correct ?

Comment: @Pritam 1299.492 is *somewhere* between those two numbers, but it is not HALF WAY between those two numbers. It will go to 1299.5 if the value is 1299.495 or more.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you call it with 1299.495, you'll still get 1299.49, because the literal 1299.495 actually ends up as 1299.4949999999998908606357872486114501953125.