# Math.Round to round always up to decimal value

Tags: c#, math, rounding

I Have this value: 833333333333333.33325
And need to round up with 2 decimals (should be 833333333333333.34)

If i use MidpointRounding.ToEven or AwayFromZero, i always get 833333333333333.33.
How i can get 833333333333333.34 using Math in C# ?

The code is:

```
decimal valorArredondado = Math.Round(valorParcelado, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Where valorParcelado is 833333333333333.33325 andi need a return in decimal value.

Comment: You are not helping us. If you could post your code would be much better

Comment: Why should it be 833333333333333.34? That's Mathematically incorrect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding up to 2 decimal places in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075201/rounding-up-to-2-decimal-places-in-c-sharp)

Comment: `833333333333333.33` is correct in your case.

Comment: Rounding up to 833333333333333.34 introduces an error of around 0.008, whereas rounding it to 833333333333333.33 introduces an error of around 0.003... which is surely better?

Comment: Hello. That's the code: decimal valorArredondado = Math.Round(valorParcelado, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
Where valorParcelado is 833333333333333.33325, and i need a return of decimal value..

Comment: @MatthewWatson: without knowing the OPs application - how do you know which is the better answer. The error may not be an issue if the requirement is to round UP to 2dp.

Comment: The possible duplicate of Rounding up to 2 decimal places in C# not solve my problem.

Comment: @PaulF It's worth asking these questions to avoid X-Y problems!

Comment: That not rounding, that's taking the ceiling value.

Comment: @user3185569: Mathematically correct does not always matter - you need to know the requirements.  I have an application which requires me to collect a minimum number of samples over a specified period of time - the required sampling rate is calculated & regardless of size of the fractional part must always be rounded up - otherwise I will not collect the minimum number of samples.

Comment: @user3185569: I think that is exactly the definition of rounding **up** with the number of decimal places specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
decimal r = Math.Ceiling(d * 100m) / 100.0m;
```

For example:

```
decimal d = 833333333333333.33325m;
decimal r = Math.Ceiling(d * 100m) / 100.0m;

Console.WriteLine(d); // 833333333333333.33325
Console.WriteLine(r); // 833333333333333.34
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the help, and sorry for bad question :/

Comment: @Jokesonme I personally didn't think it was a bad question, I was just wondering why you needed to do non-standard rounding. :)

Comment: @MatthewWatson: See my comment above for my reason for non-standard rounding.

Comment: @PaulF Rounding up (using ceiling) like you describe comes under my definition of standard "rounding"  - but taking the ceiling value after the 2nd decimal place doesn't, hence my questions. It's definitely pretty unusual.

Comment: I guess as I'm used to working in milli, micro, nano & even pico seconds the concept of rounding up to a number of decimal places fits in with my experience. I have implemented something along the lines of your solution as an extension method for decimals allowing specification of how many decimal places to round up to.