# C# float round last digit always up

Tags: c#, rounding, precision

I would like to implement a function in C# which would take a float number and it would output rounded one as this (always up):

```
1,527 -> 1,53
1,53 -> 1,6
1,6 -> 2
```

What's the easiest way to do so?

EDIT:
To clear it up a bit - I want this to set proper max value of the 2D graph axis, so if the max value is 1,527, I want to do several iterations of this function until rounded value is higher than e.g. 10%, so for 1,527 the max value could be 1,6 and thus 1,527 fits the graph which is almost fully used at the same time

Comment: What's the point? "I will always lose one digit of precision but I'm not doing this to fit the constraints of a display"? Are you sure you've interpreted the requirement correctly?

Comment: What about truncate it and add 1? `(int)(1,527 + 1)` It's against the rounding principle...

Comment: How do you want to treat negative numbers?

Comment: How do you want to treat already round integers?

Comment: `Math.Ceiling` useful if you want to rounding up. However the precision depends on formula you're using, as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075201/rounding-up-to-2-decimal-places-in-c-sharp).

Comment: What do you want to do about the fact that `double d = 1.53;` results in d having the exact value `1.530000000000000026645352591` ?

Comment: This seems particularly unuseful for floats.

Comment: Negative numbers won't be used.

Comment: @AakashM OP never talked about `double`, only `float`

Comment: @Rafalon fine, what does OP want to do about the fact that `float f = 1.53;` results in `f` having the exact value `1.5299999713897705078125`

Comment: ^if it won't prevent the number rounding like this `1.5299999713897705078125` -> `1.6` then I don't mind such inaccuracy

Comment: @Calmo well but how to know *which* digit is the one to round? You don't have `1.53` but you have `1.529999.....` so following your logic it should become `1.529999971389770507813` and not `1.6`

Comment: I use float so I expect it to be 7 digits accuracy maximum, isn't C# Math.Ceiling handling rounding floats correctly even if they true value is different?
I don't need to know or round real values, just the cut-off to float representation ones.
Does this what you mention prevent Math.Ceiling working correctly for example with:
`Math.Ceiling(1.53*10)/10`? The output here should be `1.6` right? If so, I think I don't need to think about exact values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not do it with simple multiplication by powers of 10, this effectively shift the decimal point where you can call Math.Ceiling to round the number up. Divide by the same power of 10 to put the decimal point back where it was.

Using `decimal.ToString()` to "get around" the problems of floating point precision see [this blog post](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx) for more information

```
var values = new[] { 1.527f, 1.53f, 1.6f, -1.527f };

for (var i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    var val = (decimal)values[i];

    var precision = (decimal.GetBits(val)[3] >> 16 & 0xff) - 1;

    var power = (decimal)Math.Pow(10, precision);

    if (val < 0)
        val = Math.Floor(val * power) / power;
    else
        val = Math.Ceiling(val * power) / power;

    Console.WriteLine(val);
}
```

Outputs

> 1.53
>
> 1.6
>
> 2
>
> -1.53

**NOTE** `Math.Pow` and `Math.Ceiling` are operations on `double`, hence the cast to `double` from `float`

**UPDATE** Figures out how much decimal places it needs rounding to and uses decimal which "gets around" the issues with floating point precision.

**UPDATE 2** Uses `decimal.GetBytes` to get the number's precision rather than doing the rather cumbersome culture invariant `ToString().Split` yada yada yada.

**UPDATE 3** Rounds away from zero for negative numbers and added bitwise `& 0xff` to strip off sign bit.

Comment: I was thinking about the same solution, probably the best one

Comment: Note that the "hard part" in OP's question is to **detect** the current precision. Here you just hardcode it.

Comment: How come you get 4 outputs when you only have 3 inputs, and what happened to "*using `decimal.ToString()`*"?

Comment: @Rafalon updated answer, yet again. Now handles negative numbers too :)

Comment: @Calmo updated answer to handle negative numbers too

Answer (score 1):

Using [this question's marked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477689/find-number-of-decimal-places-in-decimal-value-regardless-of-culture):

```
static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("DECIMAL");

    decimal dTest = 1.527m;
    var dTest2 = dTest;

    while(dTest2 < dTest*1.1m)
    {
        dTest2 = RoundUp(dTest2);
        Console.WriteLine(dTest2);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("FLOAT");

    float fTest = 1.527f;
    var fTest2 = fTest;

    while(fTest2 < fTest*1.1f)
    {
        fTest2 = RoundUp(fTest2);
        Console.WriteLine(fTest2);
    }
}

static decimal RoundUp(decimal input)
{
    int precision = BitConverter.GetBytes(decimal.GetBits(input)[3])[2];

    decimal factor = (decimal)Math.Pow(10,precision-1);

    return Math.Ceiling(input*factor)/factor;
}

static float RoundUp(float input)
{
    return (float)RoundUp((decimal)input);
}
```

Outputs:

```
DECIMAL
1.53
1.6
2
FLOAT
1.53
1.6
2
```

[Running example](http://tpcg.io/U9j39U)

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = "1,53";
```

Split this string into two, and count decimals number:

```
var length = a.Split(',')[1].Length;
```

Convert original string to double variable (replacing `,` to `.` to avoid Exception during convertation):

```
var b = Convert.ToDouble(a.Replace(',', '.'))
```

Perform rounding with the specified precision:

```
var c = Math.Ceil(b, (length - 1));
```

And return value with replaced `.` to `,`:

```
return c.ToString().Replace('.', ',');
```

Comment: And where is `.` in question ?

Comment: @Rafalon The question doesn't have this requirement.

Comment: I never said it had it, I just asked if it would work

Comment: Instead of Math.Round I think you should use Math.Ceiling() to always round up.

Comment: Please add some explanation around your code, so you help people to understand what you did and why. Maybe refer to some docuemtation.

Answer (score 0):

A culture indipendent solution:

```
static double RoundUp(double val)
{
    double a = val;
    double decimals = a - ((int)a); //Gets only decimals
    double pow = Math.Pow(10, decimals.ToString().Length - 3); 
    a = a * pow;             //Multiply by a power of 10 | decimal shift
    a = Math.Ceiling(a);     //Round up
    a = a / pow;             //Shift back
    return a;
}
```

and call it like:

```
var res = RoundUp(1.527); //1.53
res = RoundUp(1.53); //1.6
res = RoundUp(1.6); //2
```

or for floats:

```
static float RoundUp(float val)
{
    float a = val;
    float t = a - ((int)a); //Gets only decimals
    float pow = (float)Math.Pow(10, t.ToString().Length - 3); 
    a = a * pow;             //Multiply by a power of 10 | decimal shift
    a = (float)Math.Ceiling(a);     //Round up
    a = a / pow;             //Shift back
    return a;
}


var res = RoundUp(1.527f); //1.53
res = RoundUp(1.53f); //1.6
res = RoundUp(1.6f); //2
```