# C# Round Up Two Decimal Places in C#?

Tags: c#, floating-point, numbers, rounding

I have decimal numbers. I want to round up them with two places:

```
Original Value : 6.3619 
What I want    : 6.37

Original Value : 5.12003
What I want    : 5.13
```

I tried `Math.Celing`, `Math.Round`. But these methods don't give me the values I want.

I don't want to *truncate* decimal value.

Comment: @emert117 Should be Math.Round(integer, 2) to round to two decimal places. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257005/how-do-you-round-a-number-to-two-decimal-places-in-c

Comment: @ZoharPeled Sorry, I edited the post.

Comment: `var result = Math.Ceiling(value * 100) / 100.0;`

Comment: If decimal number has something after second place, I want to round up it not truncate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you round a number to two decimal places in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257005/how-do-you-round-a-number-to-two-decimal-places-in-c)

Comment: Don't round numbers. Round the number as string.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, try post your above comment as an answer. I think it would be useful not only for the OP but also for future reader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [Ceiling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.ceiling?view=netframework-4.7.2) method:

1. *Scale* the `value` *up*: `6.3619 -> 636.19`
2. *Truncate* with a help of `Math.Ceiling`: `636.19 -> 637`
3. Finally, *scale* the result *down*: `637 -> 6.37`

**Code:**

```
 var result = Math.Ceiling(value * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

**Demo:**

```
double[] tests = new double[] {
  6.3619,
  5.12003,
};

string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => $"{test,10} -> {Math.Ceiling(test * 100) / 100.0}"));

Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
  6.3619 -> 6.37
 5.12003 -> 5.13
```

Comment: Note: `value * 100` overflows when near the maximum `double`. Yet for large `double`, no rounding needed as all large value are whole numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this.

```
 var answer = Math.Ceiling(yourvalue * 100) / 100;
```

Please mark it as answer if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
private double RoundValueUp(double value, int NbDecimals)
{
    double multiplier = Math.Pow(10, Convert.ToDouble(NbDecimals));
    return Math.Ceiling(value * multiplier) / multiplier;
}
```

Thus you can use it like this `RoundValueUp(6.3619, 2);`
In reference to [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075201/rounding-up-to-2-decimal-places-in-c-sharp)