# How to round away from zero, when converting to a string of a specified precision (eg. 0.004 to "0.01" instead of "0.00")?

Tags: c#, .net, rounding

Is there a way to ensure that 'relevant to human visual display' information, particularly in context of [`interpolated $".." strings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) is preserved?

Use case:

```
double errors = 1.0 / 25000; // => 0.004
var errorMessage = $"Data had {errors:F2}% errors!";
```

However, the current output is a bit misleading, as it "reads as" '0%' errors.

```
Data had 0.00% errors.
```

What is a simple method in C# to achieve an output such as the following instead? (Naturally, there should be no 100.01%..)

```
Data had 0.01% errors.
```

The `Math.Round` function is not directly suitable without finagling, as the rounding applies to midpoint values, not to 'at precision'.

```
Math.Round(errors, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) // => 0; desired is 0.01
```

Comment: I suppose that is a duplicate (thanks!), *however* the accepted answer seems inferior to to one of the other answers on the same question ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/7075236/2864740 ) (which starts with a decimal, that is base-10).

Comment: floating-point precision shenanigans are unavoidable if you use floating-point variables. The `decimal` type helps you avoid this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.ceiling?view=net-5.0

Comment: MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero Doesn't work because 0.004 is not a midpoint. Perhaps you want to `*100` and math.ceil the result?

Comment: @CaiusJard Yup, that's what I was looking for as covered in the duplicate-question answers (with relevant details). I was hoping there was a built-in method for such relating to/around the string formatting (and there is not).

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest solution would be to create your own function that rounds up. Using an if statement you could do something like: if errorMargin is bigger than 0.00 and smaller than 0.01, set errorMargin to 0.01