# Fraction approximation to the nearest

Tags: c#

I have double number and i want to approximate it always to the nearest .

for eg: 1.2324    -> 1
        1.898     -> 2

how can i do this with C#?

Comment: [Using Round?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14/whats-the-difference-between-math-floor-and-math-truncate-in-net/580252#580252 - it tells you everything you need to know about the various rounding and truncating methods.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Math.Round()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

```
double d1 = Math.Round(1.2324); //d1 is 1
double d2 = Math.Round(1.898);  //d2 is 2
```

Comment: This compiles as an error "Cannot convert type double to decimal"

Comment: @1ntello: Sorry, the return type should be `double`, as the argument is `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Try Math.Round
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa340225(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: ok it worked thnx :)
but if i want to approximate : 1.567  to 1.6

Comment: Multiply by 10, round, divide by 10.

Comment: @Yasser See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

`Math.Round(double)` does the trick. If you want to use a variable number of decimals behind the decimal point you can use `Math.Round(double, int)`

The API describing this is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zy06z30k.aspx).