# Round double to top - C#

Tags: c#, math, double, rounding

I have a double number like 1,01 and I want to make it 2 when it has a oversupply??

```
double number1 = 1,01
double number2 = 1,1
double number3 = 1,00000001
```

these are must be 2

Comment: Everything you need to know about this can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14/whats-the-difference-between-math-floor-and-math-truncate-in-net/580252#580252.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
double roundedUp = Math.Ceiling(number);
```