# Converting from List<float> to int

Tags: c#, casting

Can anyone please tell me if this can be done, and if yes, how?

I have a `List<float> FocalLengthList` that I have populated with some values. Then THIS List is stored in a `List<List<float>> MainFocalLenghtList`.
However, in my application I need to use the values fromMainFocalLenghtList to update an objects 3D position. So I need to cast `fromMainFocalLenghtList [0]` to `int`.

Can this be done and how?

Here is a small section of my code to explain.
Adding values to FocalLengthList then adding that list to `List<List<float>> MainFocalLenghtList`

```
float newFocalLength = focalLength * pixelSize; 
FocalLengthList.Add(newFocalLength); 
MainFocallengthList.Add(FocalLengthList); 
FocalLengthList = new List<float>();
```

Then how I intend to use the values (not working)

```
int zComponent = MainFocallengthList[0];
```

Comment: Are you trying to cast a single float to a single int or the whole list to a list of ints? It's not clear from your question.

Comment: I was about to ask the same thing..

Comment: MainFocallenthList is a list of lists.  What would you expect the result to be if you cast a list of floats to an int?

Comment: If you are looking for, for example, the first item from the first list in MainFocallengthList, you should be able to index it as: MainFocallengthList[0][0]. For the nth item in the mth list, you'd use MainFocallengthList[m][n].

Comment: What valid conversion is there (or could there be) between `List<float>` and `int`?

Comment: May want to review the answers in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14/whats-the-difference-between-math-floor-and-math-truncate-in-net - there's a loss of precision going from float to int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way, but you need the indexes of both the inner and outer lists:

```
// The first [0] indicates the index of the nested list within MainFocallengthList
// The second [0] indicates the index of the item that you want in the nested list
int zComponent = (int)(MainFocallengthList[0][0])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly cast a `float` to an `int`, as long as you do so explicitly (since it may involve a loss of precision).

The problem with the code you've posted is that you're indexing into a list *of other lists*. The value returned by `MainFocallengthList[0]` will itself be a `List<float>`. You must then index into *that* list to get a value you can actually cast to int.

Assuming both the target list and the target float *in* that list are at the first index of their respective containers:

```
int zComponent = (int)MainFocalLengthList[0][0];
```

That first index returns the `FocalLengthList` that you added to `MainFocalLengthList`. The second index returns the `newFocalLength` value that you added to `FocalLengthList`. Clear? :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably do it like this:

```
int zComponent = (int)Math.Ceiling(MainFocallengthList[m][n]);
```

Though you'll want to substitute actual values for the *n*<sup>th</sup> item in the *m*<sup>th</sup> `FocalLengthList`.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

```
var floatList = new List<float>();

var intList = floatList.Select(f => (int)Math.Ceiling(f)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `MainFocalLengthList` is a List of `List<float>`

```
var intarr = Array.ConvertAll(MainFocalLengthList[0].ToArray(), f=>(int)f);
```