# C# Check range of value with valid increments

Tags: c#

Seems simple, but can't find an elegant way... I want to check if a value is within a certain range, but also is using a valid increment/resolution. Say my range is 0.1 to 99.9, with a resolution of .1. Valid values would be 1.1 and 1.2, but 1.15 is not valid. How would I check that?

Comment: What is the type of your value? Decimal? float?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `%` operator:

```
float i = 1.15;
Console.WriteLine((decimal)i % .1M == 0);
```

Output: `false`

```
float i = 1.1;
Console.WriteLine((decimal)i % .1M == 0);
```

Output: `true`

Comment: What if there are multiple decimals? This won't work in general.

Comment: @Tim Croydon: It only works to test if the number has more than one decimal, but what if all values in the domain (both correct and incorrect) have at least 2 decimals?

Comment: @Tudor If two decimal were valid (not in this case according to OP), you would use `.01` instead of `.1`.

Comment: @RedFilter: I suppose that's just an example and the OP can have any decimal "resolution".

Comment: Updated for `float` data type specified in subsequent comment.

Comment: Thanks guys. This did the trick, although I had to cast my double as decimal. Doing that operation on doubles doesn't work. But no big deal for me!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (for 0.1 resolution):

```
(x * 10) % 1 == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
        double a = 0.1;
        double b = 99.9;
        double x = 1.5;
        double range = 0.5;
        double epsilon = 0.000001;

        bool isRange = (x >= a) && (x <= b) && (Math.Abs((x - a)%range) < epsilon);
```

Here epsilon is some very small 'mistake' value

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with [arithmetic progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression). In your example `a[1] = 0.1`, `d = 0.1`, `a[999] = 99.9`. If your number `x` is the `n`th member of the progression then the following holds:

```
n = (x - a[1])/d + 1
```

So you have to check whether

```
(x - a[1])/d
```

is a nonegative integer. For example:

```
(1.1 - 0.1)/0.1 = 10
```

therefore 1.1 is a member of progression. However:

```
(1.15 - 0.1)/0.1 = 10.5
```

therefore 1.15 is not a member of progression.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
decimal yourDecimal = ;

if( yourDecimal % .1M == 0 )
{
    ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75ks3aby.aspx) to force it to the precision you want.  What's the difference between 1.999 and 1.2 in your application?  (See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14/difference-between-math-floor-and-math-truncate-in-net/580252#580252))