# How do I round down a double amount?

Tags: c#-4.0, math, rounding

How do I round down money values?

I basically have the following code but it does not really do what I'd like it to do.

```
double amount = 1.236356789;
Math.Round(amount, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
```

I'd like the output to be 1.23.

Comment: Math.Truncate() or Math.Floor() ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14/difference-between-math-floor-and-math-truncate-in-net

Comment: I still want to keep the numbers the numbers after the comma but round down. Basically im working with money

Comment: Not sure I see your problem then - you want to remove some numbers but still keep those numbers? Are you talking about formatting for print/display instead?

Comment: Yes im going to display the values but i want to round them down when displaying

Comment: amount.ToString("0.00") will do it then ....

Comment: @roger_rowland - It still round up to 1.24 but I want it to be 1.23

Comment: double dispAmount = Math.Truncate(amount * 100.0) / 100.0; Then use dispAmount.ToString("0.00")