# Compare decimals to 1 decimal point?

Tags: c#, compare, decimal

I'm new to C# (Come from Java/C++ at uni so it's not really that new I guess) but for a project I'm needing to compare decimals.

e.g.

```
a = 1234.123
b = 1234.142
```

`Decimal.Compare()` will of course say they're not the same as a is smaller than b. What I want to do is compare it to that first decimal place (1 and 1) so it would return true.

The only way I've been able to think of is to convert it to use `Decimal.GetBits()` but I was hoping there is a simpler way I just haven't thought of yet.

Comment: Which ever method you decide on, I would suggest creating an extension method so it becomes part of the Decimal class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [round a decimal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6be1edhb.aspx) to one fractional digit and then compare them.

```
if (Decimal.Round(d1,1) == Decimal.Round(d2,1))
    Console.WriteLine("Close enough.");
```

And, if rounding (with default midpoint handling) is not what you want, `Decimal` types can also be used with all the other options, like those I covered in [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14/difference-between-math-floor-and-math-truncate/580252#580252).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Math.Truncate(Decimal)` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d101hyf(v=vs.110).aspx))

> Calculates the integral part of a specified decimal number.

Coding example.

```
Decimal a = 1234.123m;
Decimal b = 1234.142m;

Decimal A = Math.Truncate(a * 10);  
Console.WriteLine(A);// <= Will out 12341
Decimal B = Math.Truncate(b * 10); 
Console.WriteLine(B);// <= Will out 12341

Console.WriteLine(Decimal.Compare(A, B)); // Will out 0 ; A and B are equal. Which means a,b are equal to first decimal place
```

Note : This was tested and posted .

Also simple one line comparison :

```
Decimal a = 1234.123m;
Decimal b = 1234.142m;

 if(Decimal.Compare(Math.Truncate(a*10),Math.Truncate(b*10))==0){
      Console.WriteLine("Equal upto first decimal place"); // <= Will out this for a,b
 }
```

Comment: Any reason for a downvote ? i can learn from the explanation :)

Comment: Ditto for this one, it looks like it will work fine.

Comment: Same for this - it works and is what I asked for so thank you too :P Doesn't deserve a downvote.

Comment: @KageOni You can upvote other answers (which are helpful) too :) . This will help others looking for such an answer to identify options avaialbe.

Comment: @KcDoD I've only just registered to this site so my rep is too low to upvote unfortunately but I will once it's at 15 :)