# how to leave decimal places to 1 without rounding

Tags: c#

I need to convert my value `2.8634` to `2.8`. I tried the following ,

```
var no = Math.Round(2.8634,2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

I'm getting `2.87`.

Suggest me some ideas how to convert.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might do the trick for you

```
decimal dsd = 2.8634m;
var no = Math.Truncate(dsd * 10) / 10;
```

[Math.Truncate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.truncate(v=vs.110).aspx) calculates the integral part of a specified decimal number. The number is rounded to the nearest integer towards zero.

You can also have a look on the difference between [`Math.Floor`, `Math.Ceiling`, `Math.Truncate`, `Math.Round`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/580252/3796048) with an amazing explanation.

Comment: Happy to help you @shalusri Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this one.Hope this will work for you.

```
var no = Math.Round(2.8634,1,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Comment: it's 2.9,  he wants to get 2.8

Answer (score 0):

It's a tad more cryptic (but more efficient) than calling a `Math` method, but you can simply multiply the value by 10, cast to an integer (which effectively truncates the decimal portion), and then divide by 10.0 (or `10d`/`10f`, all just to ensure we don't get integer division) to get back the value you are after. I.e.:

```
float val = 2.8634;
val = ((int)(val * 10)) / 10.0;
```