# What is the Difference between Floor and Round

Tags: php, rounding, floor

```
         CODE                            RESULTS

$a = floor(3.5);                         //3
$b = round(3.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN); //3
var_dump($a);                            //float(3)
var_dump($b);                            //float(3)
$c = gettype($a);                        //double
$d = gettype($b);                        //double
```

What are the difference.?  when do I use floor() or round() for the number above.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/580252/499581

Comment: @l'L'l the given question is not .net like in your link

Comment: @KevinWallis: No, but the concept is likely the same.

Comment: Hi @ha_rya Its more of a mathematical operation. The behaviour of round() and floor() is same irrespective the language .net, python.

Comment: does this question want to know what `floor` and `round` do? - or how the functions are implemented (technical difference)?

Comment: @I'L'l .NET and php have the same specification?

Comment: There is no difference in this case, but the functions are different in other cases. For this case you have to specify the precision and the mode for the round() function. But for other numbers these functions act different, like floor(3.6) will still be 3, but round(3.6, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) will be 4.

Comment: @Kevin Wallis I have some php script that uses round but it does not seem to work well, but floor works, they have the same values, same type so I'm kind of confused.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`floor()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) will simply drop decimal value and return only integer.

So `floor(1.2) => 1` and `floor(1.9) => 1`.

Meanwhile [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) will round number that has decimal value lower than `0.5` to lower int, and when more than `0.5` to higher int:

So `round(1.2) => 1` but `round(1.9) => 2`

Also `round()` has more options, like precision and rounding options.

---

[Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a4bf2e987b49ad2525f00b9270af5d18b26be1ca):

```php
$nums = [-1.5, -1, -.8, -.4, 0, .4, .8, 1, 1.5];

echo "    \tround\tfloor\tceil" . PHP_EOL;
foreach ($nums as $a) {
    echo $a . ": \t" . round($a) . "\t" . floor($a) . "\t" . ceil($a) . PHP_EOL;
}

/*
        round   floor   ceil
-1.5:   -2      -2      -1
  -1:   -1      -1      -1
-0.8:   -1      -1      -0
-0.4:   -0      -1      -0
   0:    0       0       0
 0.4:    0       0       1
 0.8:    1       0       1
   1:    1       1       1
 1.5:    2       1       2

*/
```

Comment: ...although if dealing with negative numbers "higher" would mean lower I presume. (eg. `round(-1.9)`) would actually go lower not higher.

Comment: why floor(-0.01) = -1
but
round(-0.01, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) = -0

Comment: @gzhegow Because your first output is wrong: https://onlinephp.io?s=s7EvyCjg5SpLLIpPKc0t0CjKL81L0dA10DMw1NS0BgA%2C&v=8.1.7

Answer (score 4):

[floor()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) will always remove the values after the decimal, and only rounds down.
[round()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) will round up if the value after the integer provided is equal or higher than .5, else it will round down.

Example 1:
round(1.5) returns 2 while floor(1.5) returns 1.

Example 2:
Both round(3.2) and floor(3.2) return 3.

Example 3:
round(2.9) returns 3 while floor(2.9) returns 2.