# Reduce Numbers after point vb.net

Tags: vb.net, precision

I am trying to reduce numbers

```
Dim x As String = 7 + 5 + 5 / 3
TextBox1.Text = x
```

the result will be `1.66666666666667`.
I want to reduce it to exactly `1.6`.

I tried this:

```
Dim x As String = 5
TextBox1.Text = String.Format("{0:N}", x / 3)
```

that reduces it to `1.667`.

But I want to reduce it to only one number after point, like `1.6`

Comment: You want `1.6` as opposed to the normally rounded `1.7`?

Comment: Turn on Option Strict  `7 + 5 + 5 / 3` is not a string

Comment: Do you want to round the number itself or print it in a short way?

Comment: Please see [Difference between Math.Floor() and Math.Truncate()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/580252/1115360) and then let us know if you change your mind about 1.6666... being shown as 1.6, and what you would like to happen for negative numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Math.Truncate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d101hyf(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dim d As Decimal = 5 / 3
TextBox1.Text = (Math.Truncate(d * 10) / 10).ToString
```

Also, consider turning option strict on because you shouldn't be feeding equations into text properties like that...and you may want to clarify that first equation in your question because it doesn't evaluate to 1.66666666666667 anyway

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Math.Round`

```
TextBox1.Text =  Math.Round(7 + 5 + 5 / 3, 2)
```

Where `2` is the number of decimals that you want to show.