# What is best practice to use when checking if decimal matches a query

Tags: c#, decimal

I have a for loop that loops a list of transactions, which all contains amount. If the amount is *correct*, I want that transaction to be included in a new list.

So in code:

```
 decimal searchAmount = 33.03;

foreach (var order in listOforders)

{ 

  if(order.amount == searchAmount)

    {
      addOrderToList()
    }

}
```

The currency used doesn't use more than two decimals, so that's okay. These three scenarios, should all add the order to the list.

```
order.Amount = 33.03
search.Amount = 33   

order.Amount = 33.03
search.Amount = 33.03

order.Amount = 33.99
search.Amount = 33.9
```

**Note:**

This is a search. When the customer comes back, and says "I have a problem with the product I purchased, and it's not purchased on a registered customer", searching for the amount on the customers bank receipt is a great function. This is a retail brick and mortar store scenario, so some customers choose to not register themselves.

Comment: Put the condition like if(order.amount>33 && order.amount<=33.03)

Comment: Can you try to elaborate on your definition of *correct*? You've just given two specific examples, can you instead try to describe what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: and what is your threshold, 33.53 should not be included?

Comment: I felt it was kinda hard to elaborate a lot, but just picture an employee who wish to search for receipts to match amount. The employee can in some cases be lazy and write just 33, in other cases 33.53. Best case would perhaps be to just search without decimals? I basically want to write the matching as good as possible.

Comment: If you are saying values like `33`, `33.03`,`33.09`... etc are need to be considered, then you can convert your value to it's `floor value`, and then you can test your conditions. For example: `value = 33.03`, `floor(value) = 33`, `searchAmount = 33.03`, `floor(searchAmount) = 33`; Like this you can develop your scenarios.

Comment: "Now to define correct," ... proceeds to define correct as either 33 or 33.03.

Comment: I added three specific scenarios, hope this is better.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/580252/7974050

Comment: This is more of a UX question. Personally I would expect to have *from* and *to* fields when filtering by an amount, rather than a single field.

Comment: Actually, this specific search is when a customer comes back with a bank receipt, and  you know the specific amount. I just want to include cases when the employee is lazy.

Comment: "employee is lazy" in entering banking data? are you sure? What is the purpose of this code?

Comment: @miniHessel In that case I would use a threshold depending on the number of digits the employee entered, e.g. for "33" return 33.00 - 33.99, for "33.0" return 33.00 - 33.09 and for "33.03" return only 33.03.

Comment: @amit This is a search. When the customer comes back, and says "I have a problem with the product I purchased, and it's not purchased on a registered customer, searching for the amount on the bank receipt is a great function. This is a retail brick and mortar store scenario,  so some customers choose to not register themselves.

Comment: @miniHessel Check my answer, if you want to allow difference upto 0.99, you can use that.

Comment: @Amit Foolproofing is always a good idea.

Comment: Am I missing something or shouldn't we just be comparing `int`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to discard the fractional part completely, using a combination of LINQ and `Math.Truncate`

```
var orders = listOfOrders.Where(o => Math.Truncate(o.amount) == Math.Truncate(searchAmount))
                         .ToList();
```

`Math.Truncate` returns the integral part of a given decimal, `Where` selects only appropriate orders (do read up on LINQ's deferred execution if you don't know it) and `ToList` materializes the query into a list.

EDIT: given your edit, this is probably what you're looking for:

```
var orders
   = listOfOrders.Where(
      o => Math.Truncate(o.amount) == Math.Truncate(searchAmount)
        && o.amount.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                   .StartsWith(searchAmount.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)))
                 .ToList();
```

This first verifies if the integral part of the numbers match and then uses string comparison to check if the actual amount starts with what was inputted (by your lazy user).

Comment: If Math.Truncate would already convert it to no decimal place, and compare it correctly, why add another && condition doing the same thing?

Comment: Because, if I'm reading the requirements correctly (I admit there's certain degree of guessing here, OP really isn't clear on these), you shouldn't match an order with amount `33.00` if your search amount was `33.9`, but you should match one with amount `33.95` for example.

Comment: On the other hand, you can't drop the `Truncate` part, otherwise search amount `3` would find orders with amount `33` for example.

Comment: Good comeback on the explanation part.

Answer (score 1):

Use your if condition like this. Round to 2 decimal places and compare.

```
     if((Math.Round(order.amount,2) - Math.Round(searchAmount,2)) <= 0.9M)

    {
      addOrderToList();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you use `Math.Truncate(number)`? Just like:

```
if(Math.Truncate(order.amount) == Math.Truncate(searchAmount))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Math.Floor` method to match all numbers i.e absolute value

```
decimal searchAmount = 33.03;
var temp = Math.Floor(searchAmount);
foreach (var order in listOforders)
{ 
  if(Math.Floor(order.amount) == temp)
  {
    addOrderToList()
  }
}
```

Comment: You're calling `Math.Floor()` multiple times on the same `searchAmount` variable. Why not just declare it as `int`?

Comment: @DiskJunky, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If am right you need to do define some maximum difference constant and use it something like that

```
decimal maxDiff = 0.03;
decimal searchAmount = 33.03;
var result =  listOfOrders.Where(o => Math.Abs(o.Amount - searchAmount) <=  maxDiff);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for any call to `Math` as a cast to `int` will do the same. Your code could be changed to;

```
int searchAmount = 33;
listOforders.Where(o => (int)o.Amount == searchAmount)
            .ForEach(o => addOrderToList());
```